# scope.$on is not working when created inside a directive

Tags: angularjs, events, broadcast, directive, emit

I have created a directive for my application which is mentioned in the following question
[How do you serve a file for download with AngularJS or Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514509/how-do-you-serve-a-file-for-download-with-angularjs-or-javascript) Directive code is as like below

```
    appModule.directive('fileDownload', function ($compile) {
        var fd = {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

                scope.$on("downloadFile", function (e, url) {
                    var iFrame = iElement.find("iframe");
                    if (!(iFrame && iFrame.length > 0)) {
                        iFrame = $("<iframe style='position:fixed;display:none;top:-1px;left:-1px;'/>");
                        iElement.append(iFrame);
                    }
                    iFrame.attr("src", url);
                });
            }
        };
        return fd;
    });
```

Here scope.$on is used, when I call this event via $scope.$emit or $scope.$broadcast, it is not working. My controller code is like below

```
    function reportsController($scope, $http) {
        var self = this;

        $scope.$broadcast("downloadFile", 'http://google.com');
        $scope.$emit("downloadFile", 'http://google.com');
    }
```

and my html file is as below

```
    <div ng-controller="reportsController" id="repctrl">
        <a file-download></a>
    </div>
```

What I am doing wrong here?

@Edit: Added the subscribe ($on) in the compile phase so as to avoid the usage of $timeout in controller. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/esy4kLm2/5/) you can look the example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your controller is being initialized before your directive.. so the `$on` starts listening after the `$emit`, `$broadcast` already happened.

see this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VATMK2JwVNiesZrgvTaU)

open the console and you can see when the console.logs happen:

```
controller init happened script.js:16
link happened script.js:7
$scope.test() happened script.js:21
scope.$on happened script.js:9
scope.$on happened
```

If you initialize the controller with `ng-view` or do the emit/broadcast after the directive is created, it should work.

Comment: why are you doing a .controller on your returned fd object?

Comment: fd is the return value of the 2nd argument of the directive function, which is just returning the directive config. The `.controller` is actually being called on the return value of `.directive`, which is a reference to the module that called it.

Answer (score 1):

something similar happen to me when i try to call a function in the directive of a modal,

what i had to do was to make a delay after I made the call to show the modal:

```
        $timeout(function () {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('obtiene-plantillas');
        }, 500);
```

Comment: Here we don't need to give the time as second argument for $timeout. I have edited my question and added my latest finding as solution in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/esy4kLm2/5/)