# How to Display blob (.pdf) in an AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, pdf, blob

I have been trying to display pdf file which I am getting as a blob from a `$http.post` response. The pdf must be displayed within the app using `<embed src>` for example.

I came across a couple of stack posts but somehow my example doesn't seem to work.

**JS:**

According to [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), I went on and tried...

```
$http.post('/postUrlHere',{myParams}).success(function (response) {
 var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
 var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
 $scope.content = fileURL;
});
```

Now from what I understand, `fileURL` creates a temporary URL that the blog can use as a reference.

**HTML:**

```
<embed src="{{content}}" width="200" height="200"></embed>
```

I am not sure how to handle this in Angular, the ideal situation would be to **(1)** assign it to a scope, **(2)** 'prepare/rebuild' the blob to a pdf **(3)** pass it to the HTML using `<embed>` because I want to display it within the app.

I have been researching for more than a day now but somehow I can't seem to understand how this works in Angular... And let's just assume the pdf viewer libraries out there weren't an option.

Comment: Hi D'lo DeProjuicer, did you manage to get your problem of generating the PDF via angular fixed ?

Comment: @michael D'lo DeProjuicer What should be done for the same case in angular 2 ?

Answer (score 222, accepted):

First of all you need to set the `responseType` to `arraybuffer`. This is required if you want to create a blob of your data. See [Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data). So your code will look like this:

```
$http.post('/postUrlHere',{myParams}, {responseType:'arraybuffer'})
  .success(function (response) {
       var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
       var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
});
```

The next part is, you need to use the [$sce](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24sce) service to make angular trust your url. This can be done in this way:

```
$scope.content = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
```

Do not forget to inject the [$sce](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24sce) service.

If this is all done you can now embed your pdf:

```
<embed ng-src="{{content}}" style="width:200px;height:200px;"></embed>
```

Comment: For me this did not work in Chrome (35.0.1916.114 m). Solved this by using <object> instead of <embed>: <object data="{{content}}" type="application/pdf"></object>

Comment: Hi Michael and HoffZ, which js libraries did you include to have your PDF generated as I am experiencing problems about the file(PDF) being corrupt, it's generated but doesn't display in my case.

Comment: For me (AngularJS 1.25) I had to do: new Blob([response.data]

Comment: @HoffZ: I replaced the shortcut method `$http.get` with a full one, specifying the `responseType` field: ```{
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/resources/jobs/af471106-2e71-4fe6-946c-cd1809c659e5/result/?key="+$scope.key,
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
               'Accept': 'application/pdf'
            },
            responseType: 'arraybuffer'
        }```
And it works :)

Comment: Not sure why, since @michael follows the [specification](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). The only difference in my case: I use `GET`, not post. [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447952/angularjs-http-post-convert-binary-to-excel-file-and-download) for my solution.

Comment: Using ng-src didn't work with the embed tag when you change the src in the controller, so it loads first time but if you change the src because of a click for example then the src in the embed tag doesn't change.
It is working fine with object tag though

Comment: hi, you solutions worked like charm...is there a way to remove PDF toolbar...i tried toolbar=0 navpanes=0 scrollbar =0 but not working

Comment: For me the only way to make it work was to create the blob with `response.data` instead of `response`, like this: `var file = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});`

Comment: or if you like it opened in new windows 
     `     $window.open($sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL));     `

Comment: @yosep-kim this does not work on IE because of URL object does not exist in IE: http://caniuse.com/#search=URL

Comment: Hi Friends,
 $http.get("xx.pdf", {responseType:'arraybuffer'})
            .success(function (response) {  var file = new Blob([(response)], {type: 'application/pdf'});
               var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
               $scope.content=$sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL); });
the above one is working for me. But,
When i pass converted array byte like document to pdf array byte which is coming in response instead of xx.pdf file.  The pdf is loaded with out content. i can see the page count as 15.
Can you help me  on this issue like how to show the content.

Comment: You can simply use {responseType:'arraybuffer'} when you make a request, and then location.href = fileURL.

Answer (score 34):

I use AngularJS v1.3.4

**HTML:**

```
<button ng-click="downloadPdf()" class="btn btn-primary">download PDF</button>
```

**JS controller:**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('xxxxxxxxApp')
    .controller('xxxxController', function ($scope, xxxxServicePDF) {
        $scope.downloadPdf = function () {
            var fileName = "test.pdf";
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.style = "display: none";
            xxxxServicePDF.downloadPdf().then(function (result) {
                var file = new Blob([result.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
                a.href = fileURL;
                a.download = fileName;
                a.click();
            });
        };
});
```

**JS services:**

```
angular.module('xxxxxxxxApp')
    .factory('xxxxServicePDF', function ($http) {
        return {
            downloadPdf: function () {
            return $http.get('api/downloadPDF', { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).then(function (response) {
                return response;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**Java REST Web Services - Spring MVC:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadPDF", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/pdf")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getPDF() {
        FileInputStream fileStream;
        try {
            fileStream = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\xxxxx\\xxxxxx\\test.pdf"));
            byte[] contents = IOUtils.toByteArray(fileStream);
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
            String filename = "test.pdf";
            headers.setContentDispositionFormData(filename, filename);
            ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(contents, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
            return response;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           System.err.println(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: which version of safari? window.URL is good in safari 9 and after: http://caniuse.com/#search=createObjectURL

Comment: I tested and valided on my MacBook pro and safari 9.0.2.

Comment: Same, macBook el captain. window.URL.createObjectURL(file); i dont where is the problem but code doesnt work. May be i do something wrong. Any thank you. I haven't time to check what it not working and use FileSaver.js

Comment: if your application is online, post your URL please? have you the same Back-End?

Comment: download attribute is not supported in safari. http://caniuse.com/#search=download

Comment: @Biswanath, which version of safari? window.URL is good in safari 9 and after: caniuse.com/#search=createObjectURL

Comment: @sgrillon: I was mentioning the download attribute http://caniuse.com/#search=download

Comment: in api/downloadPDF - > which is containing only bytearray. if bytearray, it is not working for me. if i give local file as x.pdf. then my pdf is rendering on page. i dont want to download. 
i need to show the pdf file in the page itself using angular.
can you give your solutions for showing pdf file in view

Comment: if you put "application/pdf" in a header, your pdf is open in tab browser. in java => headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));

Answer (score 23):

michael's suggestions works like a charm for me :)
If you replace $http.post with $http.get, remember that the .get method accepts 2 parameters instead of 3... this is where is wasted my time... ;)

controller:

```
$http.get('/getdoc/' + $stateParams.id,     
{responseType:'arraybuffer'})
  .success(function (response) {
     var file = new Blob([(response)], {type: 'application/pdf'});
     var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
     $scope.content = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
});
```

view:

```
<object ng-show="content" data="{{content}}" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></object>
```

Comment: `responseType:'arraybuffer'`, just saved me a couple of sleeping hours! +1

Comment: how to trigger the save instead to print it in html?

Comment: thank you, this saved me a couple of hours, you can also replace `$scope.content = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);` with `$window.open(fileURL, '_self', '');` and open the file on fullscreen.

Answer (score 10):

I faced difficulties using "window.URL" with Opera Browser as it would result to "undefined". Also, with window.URL, the PDF document never opened in Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge (it would remain waiting forever). I came up with the following solution that works in IE, Edge, Firefox, Chrome and Opera (have not tested with Safari):

```
$http.post(postUrl, data, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
.success(success).error(failed);

function success(data) {
   openPDF(data.data, "myPDFdoc.pdf");
};

function failed(error) {...};

function openPDF(resData, fileName) {
    var ieEDGE = navigator.userAgent.match(/Edge/g);
    var ie = navigator.userAgent.match(/.NET/g); // IE 11+
    var oldIE = navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/g); 

    var blob = new window.Blob([resData], { type: 'application/pdf' });

    if (ie || oldIE || ieEDGE) {
       window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
    }
    else {
       var reader = new window.FileReader();
       reader.onloadend = function () {
          window.location.href = reader.result;
       };
       reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    }
}
```

Let me know if it helped! :)

Comment: This approach does not open the PDF document in the browser window in IE but prompts the user to download it. Is there any work around this?

Comment: The above code is to download the PDF file and let your default PDF Reader app take over to open it. It even works well on mobile devices. Reason is, while I was able to open the PDF on some browsers, I could not open it on other ones. So I thought it was best to have a solution that would run on all browsers (including mobile browsers) to download the PDF file.

Comment: You can use the following code to view the PDF in a new tab:                                 window.open(reader.result, '_blank');

Answer (score 6):

Adding **responseType** to the request that is made from angular is indeed the solution, but for me it didn't work until I've set **responseType** to *blob*, not to arrayBuffer. The code is self explanatory:

```
    $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : 'api/paperAttachments/download/' + id,
            responseType: "blob"
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
             var blob = new Blob([response.data]);
             FileSaver.saveAs(blob, getFileNameFromHttpResponse(response));
        }, function errorCallback(response) {   
        });
```

Comment: actually, with `'blob'` type it is possible to write shorter:
`FileSaver.saveAs(response.data, getFileNameFromHttpResponse(response));` No need to create `Blob`

Answer (score 1):

Most recent answer (for Angular 8+):

```
this.http.post("your-url",params,{responseType:'arraybuffer' as 'json'}).subscribe(
  (res) => {
    this.showpdf(res);
  }
)};

public Content:SafeResourceUrl;
showpdf(response:ArrayBuffer) {
  var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
  var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  this.Content = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(fileURL);
}

  HTML :

  <embed [src]="Content" style="width:200px;height:200px;" type="application/pdf" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled for the past couple of days trying to download pdfs and images,all I was able to download was simple text files.

Most of the questions have the same components, but it took a while to figure out the right order to make it work.

Thank you @Nikolay Melnikov, your comment/reply to this question was what made it work.

In a nutshell, here is my AngularJS Service backend call:

```
  getDownloadUrl(fileID){
    //
    //Get the download url of the file
    let fullPath = this.paths.downloadServerURL + fileId;
    //
    // return the file as arraybuffer 
    return this.$http.get(fullPath, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.sessionService.getToken()
      },
      responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    });
  }
```

From my controller:

```
downloadFile(){
   myService.getDownloadUrl(idOfTheFile).then( (response) => {
      //Create a new blob object
      let myBlobObject=new Blob([response.data],{ type:'application/pdf'});

      //Ideally the mime type can change based on the file extension
      //let myBlobObject=new Blob([response.data],{ type: mimeType});

      var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL
      var fileURL = url.createObjectURL(myBlobObject);
      var downloadLink = angular.element('<a></a>');
      downloadLink.attr('href',fileURL);
      downloadLink.attr('download',this.myFilesObj[documentId].name);
      downloadLink.attr('target','_self');
      downloadLink[0].click();//call click function
      url.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);//revoke the object from URL
    });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

A suggestion of code that I just used in my project using AngularJS v1.7.2

```
$http.get('LabelsPDF?ids=' + ids, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
            .then(function (response) {
                var file = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                $scope.ContentPDF = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
            });

<embed ng-src="{{ContentPDF}}" type="application/pdf" class="col-xs-12" style="height:100px; text-align:center;" />
```

Comment: please add some brief too.