# PDF Blob - Pop up window not showing content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf

I have been working on [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628378/angularjs-display-blob-pdf-in-an-angular-app) for the last few days. With no luck on trying to display the stream on `<embed src>` tag, I just tried to display it on a new window.

The new window shows PDF **controls only**  [image])

Any idea why the content of the pdf is not showing?

**CODE:**

```
$http.post('/fetchBlobURL',{myParams}).success(function (data) {
    var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    window.open(fileURL);
});
```

Comment: Use `$window` (with a dollar sign).

Comment: See my question and answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41390623/post-complex-data-and-open-generated-pdf-in-new-window

Comment: As Groppe shows on the answer, createObjectURL doesn't work on Internet Explorer, you have to use msSaveOrOpenBlob instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007073/open-links-made-by-createobjecturl-in-ie11

Answer (score 178, accepted):

You need to set the `responseType` to `arraybuffer` if you would like to create a `blob` from your response data:

```
$http.post('/fetchBlobURL',{myParams}, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
   .success(function (data) {
       var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
       var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
       window.open(fileURL);
});
```

more information: [Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. When typing the URL in the browser window, it works, but not via the $http.post method. Is there anything else to pay attention to? Security settings? Browser type and version?

Comment: It is working now. Seems the arrayBuffer was implemented as of v.1.1 in angularjs. I had v.1.08. When upgrading angularjs, everything worked just fine.

Comment: This almost works for me. I need to do the same, but I have to set a user-friendly URL or fileName. The UUID that browser sets it doesn't work for me. Do you know if there is a way to open a PDF in a new tab and set the file name in the URL? Thanks!

Comment: Can you help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63187758/issue-while-printing-pdf-files-from-blob-agnular  ?

Comment: URL.createObjectURL() is deprecated from Chrome 71.
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/10/chrome-71-deps-rems
You can not use it anymore.

Comment: @BojanGolubovic from how I read this the function has not been deprecated in general but only in combination with `MediaStream`. The function still exists today in Chromium based browsers. So, this answer should still be valid.

Answer (score 31):

If you set `{ responseType: 'blob' }`, no need to create `Blob` on your own. You can simply create url based with response content:

```
$http({
    url: "...",
    method: "POST",
    responseType: "blob"
}).then(function(response) {
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
    window.open(fileURL);
});
```

Comment: Excellent! This worked for me after spending many hours trying to display the pdf content.

Comment: ncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
    at Object.success (enquiry.js:68)
    at j (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
    at x (jquery.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:4)

Comment: @ThakhaniTharage which browser do you use? Check [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)

Comment: Can you help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63187758/issue-while-printing-pdf-files-from-blob-agnular  ?

Comment: how about when the response is not there and application/pdf is the response

Comment: @DaltonKim what do you mean response is not here? response.data is `null`? It was long time ago, but i believe it handles it correctly. Worst case you can add if statement

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.. The createObjectURL cannot understand the mimetype of content

Answer (score 10):

I use AngularJS v1.3.4

**HTML:**

```
<button ng-click="downloadPdf()" class="btn btn-primary">download PDF</button>
```

**JS controller:**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('xxxxxxxxApp')
    .controller('MathController', function ($scope, MathServicePDF) {
        $scope.downloadPdf = function () {
            var fileName = "test.pdf";
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            MathServicePDF.downloadPdf().then(function (result) {
                var file = new Blob([result.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
                a.href = fileURL;
                a.download = fileName;
                a.click();
            });
        };
});
```

**JS services:**

```
angular.module('xxxxxxxxApp')
    .factory('MathServicePDF', function ($http) {
        return {
            downloadPdf: function () {
            return $http.get('api/downloadPDF', { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).then(function (response) {
                return response;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**Java REST Web Services - Spring MVC:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadPDF", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/pdf")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getPDF() {
        FileInputStream fileStream;
        try {
            fileStream = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\xxxxx\\xxxxxx\\test.pdf"));
            byte[] contents = IOUtils.toByteArray(fileStream);
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
            String filename = "test.pdf";
            headers.setContentDispositionFormData(filename, filename);
            ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(contents, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
            return response;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           System.err.println(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You are not required to set the response type if your data is a byte array, make sure you convert it to Uint8Array before passing it to blob.

Example:

```
let byteArray = new Uint8Array(data)
let file = new Blob(
  [byteArray],
  {type: 'application/pdf'}
)
```

It works for me.

If your data is not byteArray, make sure to convert it to byteArray and follow above-mentioned steps to make it work.

```
//For example if your data is base-64 encoded string.
let byteChars = atob(data); //To decrypt data
let dataArray = = new Array(byteChars.length);
for(let i=0; i< byteChars.length; i++){
   dataArray[i] = byteChars.charCodeAt(i);
}
let byteArray = new Uint8Array(dataArray)
let file = new Blob(
  [byteArray],
  {type: 'application/pdf'}
)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// I used this code with the fpdf library.
// Este código lo usé con la libreria fpdf.

var datas = json1;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "carpeta/archivo.php");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onload = function () {
    if (this.status === 200) {
        var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.open(url,"_blank");
        setTimeout(function () {
            // For Firefox it is necessary to delay revoking the ObjectURL
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(datas)
                , 100
        })
    }
};
xhr.send("men="+datas);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but since this pointed me in the right direction, I thought I would share what I am doing in case someone else lands here. I am not using Angular btw.

The user can view or download the file. The choice is given with 2 buttons or 2 links

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm show_tooltip download-form" title="Download File" data-formid="{{ @your-id }}" data-forcedownload="1">
    <i class="fas fa-file-download"></i>
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm show_tooltip download-form" title="View File" data-formid="{{ @your-id }}" data-forcedownload="0">
    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
</button>
```

I am using jQuery with the native plugin for xhr2. This handles the link/buttons

```
$('.download-form').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let fid = $(this).data('formid');
    let force_download = $(this).data('forcedownload');
    $.ajax({
          url: '/download',
          dataType: 'native',
          type: 'POST',
          xhrFields: {
              responseType: 'blob'
          },
          data: {
               //you can send any parameters via POST here
               personID: "{{ @personID }}",
               file_record_id: pfid,
               file_type: "contract_form",
               dept: "your-dept",
               file_category: "fcategory",
               force_download: force_download
           },
           success: function(blob, status, xhr){
                if (xhr.getResponseHeader('Custom-FileError')>1) {
                      alertify.error(xhr.getResponseHeader('Custom-ErrorMsg'));
                }else{
                      //I thought this would work when viewing the PDF but it does not.
                      blob.name = xhr.getResponseHeader('Custom-FileName');
                      var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                      if (xhr.getResponseHeader('Custom-ForceDownload')==1) {
                            window.open(fileURL);
                            var link=document.createElement('a');
                            link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                            link.download=xhr.getResponseHeader('Custom-FileName');
                            link.click();
                       }else{
                            file_modal(fileURL,'Any Title');
                       }
                       
                   }
              }
           })
});
```

Then, some more javascript for the modal

```
function file_modal(blob,the_title)
{

    let spinner = "<div class='text-center'><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-5x fa-fw'></i></div>";
    $("#modal_static_label").html('Loading');
    $("#modal_static .modal-body").html(spinner);
    if (blob.length > 1) {
        $("#modal_static").modal("show");
        $("#modal_static_label").html(the_title);
        $("#modal_static .modal-body").empty().append('<iframe src='+blob+' width="100%" height="500px" style="border:none;"></iframe>');
    }else{
         $("#modal_static .modal-body").empty().html('File error');
    }
    $("#modal_static .modal-footer").html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>');
        
}
```

On the server side you will need to send custom headers like this [PHP]

```
header("Content-length: $file_size");
header("Custom-FileError: 0");
header("Custom-FileName: ".$this->params['original_filename']);
header("Custom-ForceDownload: ".$this->params['force_download']);
header('Content-Type: '.$web->mime($this->full_path.$this->new_file_name));
readfile($this->full_path.$this->new_file_name);
```

If the user clicks "view", a modal will display the PDF if they click "download", the download window will show up with the filename of your choosing. I have tested this with PDF files less than 10mb and it works as expected.

I hope someone finds this useful.

Comment: ```
xhrFields: {
              responseType: 'blob'
          },
``` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling for days finally the solution which worked for me is given below. I had to make the `window.print()` for PDF in new window needs to work.

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', pdfUrl, true);
      xhr.responseType = 'blob';

      xhr.onload = function(e) {
        if (this['status'] == 200) {          
          var blob = new Blob([this['response']], {type: 'application/pdf'});
          var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          var printWindow = window.open(url, '', 'width=800,height=500');
          printWindow.print()
        }
      };

      xhr.send();
```

Some notes on loading PDF & printing in a new window.

- Loading pdf in a new window via an iframe will work, but the print will not work if url is an external url.
- Browser pop ups must be allowed, then only it will work.
- If you try to load iframe from external url and try `window.print()` you will get empty print or elements which excludes `iframe`. But you can trigger print manually, which will work.

Comment: This did not work for me i got enquiry.js:85 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'print' of null
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload

Comment: Does new window opened? This sample has been worked for me earlier.

Comment: Nop it does not

Comment: pdf URL must be from the same server. Otherwise, it will show CORS error.

Comment: See the working sample link https://pdf-print-pckrishnadas88.c9users.io/hello-world.html. Please note it will be available for few hours as it is a free account.

Comment: print? just open PDF.

Answer (score 0):

problem is, it is not converted to proper format. Use function **"printPreview(binaryPDFData)"** to get print preview dialog of binary pdf data.
you can comment script part if you don't want print dialog open.

```
printPreview = (data, type = 'application/pdf') => {
    let blob = null;
    blob = this.b64toBlob(data, type);
    const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const theWindow = window.open(blobURL);
    const theDoc = theWindow.document;
    const theScript = document.createElement('script');
    function injectThis() {
        window.print();
    }
    theScript.innerHTML = `window.onload = ${injectThis.toString()};`;
    theDoc.body.appendChild(theScript);
};

b64toBlob = (content, contentType) => {
    contentType = contentType || '';
    const sliceSize = 512;
     // method which converts base64 to binary
    const byteCharacters = window.atob(content); 

    const byteArrays = [];
    for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
        const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
        const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }
    const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {
        type: contentType
    }); // statement which creates the blob
    return blob;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I ended up just downloading my pdf using below code

```
function downloadPdfDocument(fileName){

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", "/pdf/" + fileName, true);
req.responseType = "blob";
fileName += "_" + new Date() + ".pdf";

req.onload = function (event) {

    var blob = req.response;

    //for IE
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
    } else {

        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = fileName;
        link.click();
    }
};

req.send();
```

}

Comment: it starts download.

Comment: That's what I wanted, That's why it's in a function so that I can call it when I am ready to do the download. Not sure why you downvoted

Comment: that is what i wanted also :-)

Answer (score -3):

[image: let url = "data:application/pdf;base64," + base64PdfFile fetch(url) .then(res => res.blob()) .then(response => { console.log(response); let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(response); let link = document.createElement("a"); link.target = "_blank"; link.href = url; document.body.appendChild(link); link.click(); });]

Note: this.file should be you base64 file