# Embed PDF w/POST Parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, post, embed

I need to pass a bunch of parameters to a web API method which returns a byte array that is needed to display a PDF report on a page. I tried doing this via a GET method but the query string is too long and it throws an exception. I have tried shortening the query string as much as physically possibly but it is still too long. All of the external PDF viewer libraries require a string path to the PDF. I need something that allows me to supply a string path and some parameters or just a string path but that uses a POST instead of a GET. I was thinking about POSTing the object values to the web API along with a GUID and storing it somehow on the server then with an  tag calling another API method and retrieving the stored data by only passing the GUID as a parameter but I don't want to make a database table for only that to save and retrieve the data. I entertained the idea of saving the byte array to a PDF on the server and then simply pointing a PDF viewer to that after but I had no success with that either and that is not ideal.

```
    File.WriteAllBytes(path, res);
```

The code above is the most common way I have found to save the file but when I open the new PDF file after it says it is corrupt and it won't allow me to open it. Ideally I would just find a method that allows me to POST data to my web API then embeds the result in a pdf.js/pdfObject/ control. Please help, this has stumped me for days. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729451/pdf-blob-pop-up-window-not-showing-contnet/21730535#21730535

Comment: Way to go man that worked!! Thanks you are my hero!!!!