# Javascript: Open PDF in new tab from byte array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pdf, arrays

I'm using AngularJS with an HTTP resource to call an external API and my response is a byte array. I need to turn this byte array into a PDF in a new window. I haven't seen any very good solutions on here that work cross browser or that are pure javascript. Is there a way to do this?

Here is my code:

**Javascript**

```
Document.preview({id: $scope.order.id}, function(data){

    // Open PDF Here
    var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    window.open(fileURL);

});
```

Comment: http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js have some good reference here

Comment: I've been looking at that, but I don't see any good examples using a byte array.

I've also been looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628378/angularjs-display-blob-pdf-in-an-angular-app

but I'm just getting an error "Failed to load PDF Document"

Comment: Are there any proprietary plugins or anything to do this? Several pages open pdf's, how can I?

Answer (score 26):

You would need to pass the responseType in your service call

```
$http.post('/Service-URL', dataTO, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'});
```

then in the success of your data call this should open up pdf in a new window:-

```
    getDocument()
        .success(function(data) {
            var file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            window.open(fileURL);
    })
```

From this answer :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21730535/3645957  by  https://stackoverflow.com/users/2688545/michael

Comment: @ihodonald It is an Optional attribute 'name'. 
It was a typo in the answer. 
But it is optional, so not necessary. like from here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp   -> i removed it from the answer.

Comment: Dude, this thing: {responseType: 'arraybuffer'} save my life. Thank you very much! 

Answer (score 18):

If anyone still looks for that, here is what I'm doing (and working) :

```
var pdfAsDataUri = "data:application/pdf;base64,"+byteArray;
window.open(pdfAsDataUri);
```

Where byteArray is the data you receive. It's maybe not a nice solution (byte array is visible in the URL), but it works...

Comment: Data URI's don't work on all browsers.  Especially even recent versions of IE.

Comment: now chrome v60 not allowing to open file from byteArray using window.open , it has depreciated in chrome v60

Comment: tried with v94 and it worked

Comment: Nice. works with Chrome 108 version. I need to quickly verify a bytearray and this method is useful