# Vue3 Display PDF Document

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I can grab images and display them in a browser using them as a bytearray without any problem. In Normal C# I was also able to do this with PDFs very easily by inserting this bytearray as an  but now in Vue3 I am having troubles doing this same thing I've done in the past. What is a simple way to display a PDF document In browser with Vuejs?

This is how I've done in in the past,
I am open to suggestions and a better way to do this.
This will be hosted and be shown on a big screen TV so the department can view the document and it will flash to other ones as well.

```
     <div v-if="byteArrayPDF" class="content">
        <object data="byteArrayPDF" type="application/pdf" style="height:700px;width:1100px;"></object>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>
<script lang="js">
    import Vue from 'vue';

    export default Vue.extend({
        data() {
            return {
                loading: false,
                byteArrayPDF: null
            };
        },
        created() {
            this.fetchByteArray();
        },
        methods: {
            fetchByteArray() {
                this.byteArrayPDF = true;
                this.loading = null;
                
            fetch('https://localhost:5001/api/Doc/Virtual-Visual-Service-2020.pdf')
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(bytespdf => {
                        this.byteArrayPDF = "data:application/pdf;base64," + bytespdf;
                        this.loading = false;
                        return;
                    })
                    .catch(console.log("Error PDF View"));
            }
```

Comment: ***now in Vue3 I am having troubles ...*** what are they?

Comment: you're mixing up your assignments at the start of fetchByteArray() , set loading to true not byteArrayPDF , would also help to set loading to false in finally() instead of then() - if an error is thrown the loading won't reset, should find a solution or at least some help here https://stackoverflow.com/q/28197179/12476007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved this. I ended up turning the PDF / Image / Word doc / etc into a byte array and displaying that on the page.

```
<template>
    <iframe :src="byteArrayPDF" width="800px" height="800px"></iframe>
</template>
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
    data() {
        return {
            loading: false,
            post: null,
            byteArrays: null,
            byteArrayPDF: null
        };
    },
    created() {
        this.fetchByteArray();
    }, 
    //watch: {

    //}
    methods: {
        fetchByteArray() {
            this.post = true;
            this.byteArrayPDF = true;
            this.loading = null;
            this.byteArrays = null;

            console.log("Inside PDF fetchByteArray()");
            
        //fetch('https://localhost:5001/api/Doc/Virtual-Visual-Service-2020.pdf')
            fetch('https://localhost:5001/api/Doc/GetFolder/Shipment')
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.ok) {
                        this.byteArrays = true;
                        console.log("resp ok");
                        response.json().then(bytesPDF => {
                            bytesPDF.forEach((b) => {
                                if (b.fileName === "pdfdoc01.pdf") {
                                    console.log(b.fileName + " exists!");
                                    if (b.byteArray !== "") {
                                        this.byteArrayPDF = "data:application/pdf;base64," + b.byteArray;
                                    }

                                }
                            })
                        })
                    }
                })
```

I'm adding bits and pieces together because I have a service class that this method is in.

```
 var stream = File.OpenRead(file);
                        using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
                            while((read = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) > 0)
                            {
                                memoryStream.Write(bytes, 0, read);
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine(memoryStream.ToArray());
                            fileObj.ByteArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
                        }

        [Route("GetFolder/{folderName}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetFolder(string folderName)
    {
        var fileObj = _fileService.GetFolder(folderName);
        if (fileObj?.Count > 0)
        {
            return Ok(fileObj);
        }

        return BadRequest();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you said in your question, I think you want to load a **pdf** file in for example a "vue component". If that is right, you can use a code like the code below:

```html
<template>

  <div v-if="byteArrayPDF">
    <iframe :src="srcData" width="100%" height="500px">
    </iframe>
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    loading...
  </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "CompoPdf",
  data() {
    return {
      srcData: null,
      byteArrayPDF: false,
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchByteArray();
  },
  methods: {

    fetchByteArray: async function () {
      // to see the "loading..." effect, I intentionally add a "setTimeout" code. that loads the pdf after "3s". You can remove it in your real app.
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
      fetch('https://www.antennahouse.com/hubfs/xsl-fo-sample/pdf/basic-link-1.pdf')
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            // for this case "response.url" is what we need, but if you fetch data for example from a database ... you may need "response.json()" or other codes;
            this.srcData = response.url;
            this.byteArrayPDF = true;
          })
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

I also suggest that you read more about [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) if you are not familiar with that topics, to better manage your request to the url you want.