# Angular4 show image from server

Tags: angular

I want to show an image in img tag :
i am doing it that way

**Component**

```
this.file.url=this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(this.file.url));
```

**Template**

```
<img [src]="file.url">
```

I am getting this error

```
ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
```

Comment: what does createObjectUrl method do ?  please point it

Comment: @RahulSingh I was getting the unsafe error so i have followed  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39734409/angular2-and-window-url-createobjecturl

Comment: can you just directly use the file path i:e `this.file.url`

Comment: @RahulSingh  When i delete it, Angular add it is host address to the url and i get 404 error

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should set `responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob` in your GET-Request settings, because so you can get your image as blob and convert it later da base64-encoded source. You code above is not good. If you would like to do this correctly, then create separate service to get images from API. Beacuse it ism't good to call HTTP-Request in components.

Here is an working example:

Create `image.service.ts` and put following code:

```
    getImage(imageUrl: string): Observable<File> {
        return this.http
            .get(imageUrl, { responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob })
            .map((res: Response) => res.blob());
    }
```

Now you need to create some function in your `image.component.ts` to get image and show it in html.

For creating an image from Blob you need to use JavaScript's `FileReader`.
Here is function which creates new `FileReader` and listen to FileReader's load-Event. As result this function returns base64-encoded image, which you can use in img src-attribute:

```
imageToShow: any;

createImageFromBlob(image: Blob) {
       let reader = new FileReader();
       reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
          this.imageToShow = reader.result;
       }, false);

       if (image) {
          reader.readAsDataURL(image);
       }
}
```

If you have more then one image, you can define `imageToShow[] = []` as array. And now you can simple push `reader.result` to this array. For example: `this.imageToShow.push(reader.result)`. In your template you can iterate and output this array with `*ngFor="let image of imageToShow;"`.

Now you should use your created `ImageService` to get image from api. You should to subscribe to data and give this data to `createImageFromBlob`-function. Here is an example function:

```
getImageFromService() {
      this.isImageLoading = true;
      this.imageService.getImage(yourImageUrl).subscribe(data => {
        this.createImageFromBlob(data);
        this.isImageLoading = false;
      }, error => {
        this.isImageLoading = false;
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

Now you can use your `imageToShow`-variable in HTML template like this:

```
<img [src]="imageToShow"
     alt="Place image title"
     *ngIf="!isImageLoading; else noImageFound">
<ng-template #noImageFound>
     <img src="fallbackImage.png" alt="Fallbackimage">
</ng-template>
```

I hope this description is clear to understand and you can use it in your project.

Comment: Since Http module is deprecated in favor of HttpClient small changes are required (ResponseContentType is deprecated) :                                                                                             getImage(imageUrl: string): Observable<File> {
        return this.http
            .get(imageUrl, { responseType: 'blob' })
            .map((res: Response) => res.blob());
    }

Answer (score 1):

Here is a useful pipe I found online that may help you accomplish what you are trying to do.

```
import {Pipe} from '@angular/core';
import {DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, 
SafeResourceUrl} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe {

  constructor(protected _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {

  }

  public transform(value: string, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
      case 'html':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
      case 'style':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
      case 'script':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
      case 'url':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
      case 'resourceUrl':
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unable to bypass security for invalid type: ${type}`);
    }
  }
}
```

So if you are getting some type of unsafe error, then try the pipe like

```
<iframe [src]="embedUrl | safe: 'resourceUrl'"  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

If it is not a resourceUrl, try url, or any of the other options in the pipe. Does this solve your problem?