# Angular4 add it's hostname to image src

Tags: angular

When trying to show images from server :
**Template**

```
<img [src]="file.url">
```

**Component** 
(1) when i try this

```
  this.file.url="http://localhost:4000/uploads/results/101_5.png";
```

It works fine 
(2) But when doing,

```
 this.file.url=this.fromServer.url; // URl from server
```

Doesn't work and Angular add a it's host and i get this error :

```
101_5.png:1 GET http://localhost:4000/uploads/results/101_5.png 404 (Not Found)
```

(3) even this way :

```
this.file.url= "http://"+this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.fromServer.url);
```

getting this error

```
src="http://SafeValue must use [property]=binding: http://localhost:400 .... (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)
```

Comment: What's the diffrence with your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45720756/angular4-show-image-from-server

Answer (score 2):

In **index.html** set [base href](https://angular.io/guide/router#base-href)

```
<base href="/">
```

If your folder structure was something like this:

```
+src
 +app
 +assets
  +images
   logo-large.png
```

Then this would work:

`<img src="assets/images/logo-large.png"/>`

*ng serve* essentially performs an *ng build* in memory so the assets configured in **.angular-cli.json** should be available.

```
"assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
```

Which also means that the output of *ng build* can be used to preview what is available via *ng serve*

Comment: The image i am trying to get is from the server

Comment: OP's images are apparently from another directory tree than the angular app one, accessed via another server.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this in your Component :

```
this.file.url = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.fromServer.url);
```

or

```
this.file.url = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl("http://" + this.fromServer.url);
```

(or with other bypassSecurityTrustUrl 's family functions to suit your needs)

You should not try to concatenate the result of the function (of type SafeUrl) with a string.