# Get User Photo from MS Graph API and display image

Tags: typescript, microsoft-graph-api, angular5

I do apologize that this is a very specific question, but I'm desperate and I'd appreciate any hints/directions.

The scenario is the following: I'm making an `HTTP GET` request to retrieve a [`profilePhoto`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/profilephoto) and update the image profile in my Angular application.

This is my `graph.service`:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Headers } from "@angular/http";
import { AdalService } from "../adal/adal.service";

@Injectable()
export class GraphService {
  private graphUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/";

  constructor(private http: Http, private adalService: AdalService) {}

  public userPhoto(upn: string) {
    return this.http
      .get(
        this.graphUri +
          "users/" +
          this.adalService.userInfo.profile.upn +
          "/photo/$value",
        { headers: this.headers() }
      )
      .map(res => res);
  }

  private headers() {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.set("Authorization", this.adalService.token);
    return headers;
  }
}
```

On the `home.component` where I'm intending to use it, I have:

```
this.graphService.userPhoto().subscribe(resp => {
  if (resp.status === 200) {
    const dataToString = resp.arrayBuffer();
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(dataToString);
    // Here there's an error:
    // 'Argument of type Array Buffer is not assignable
    //  to parameter of type Blob.
    const image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + dataToString;
    document.getElementById("photo").setAttribute("src", image);
  }
});
```

I don't even know if I'm on the right path, to be honest... I've read somewhere about `FileReader`. But at first, this was my attempt:

```
this.graphService.userPhoto().subscribe(resp => {
  if (resp.status === 200) {
    const dataToString = resp.text();
    const image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + btoa(encodeURI(dataToString));
    document.getElementById("photo").setAttribute("src", image);
  }
});
```

`dataToString` contains something like:
``` ����JFIF``��C ``` which I understand it to be the binary data.

Just to be clear, the `GET` request returns `200`, the bearer token is valid. I'm just somehow failing to display it...

What am I doing wrong? How one should approach it?

Many thanks!

**Edit 1:** @RasmusW - The only reason of why I've added the `encodeURI` call is because without it I'll get the following error:

```
ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.
```

With the `encodeURI` my `img` HTML tag will look something like that:

```
<img _ngcontent-c2="" id="photo" src="data:image/jpeg;base64, JUVGJUJGJUJEJUVGJUJGJUJEJUVGJUJGJUJEJUVGJUJGJUJEJTAwJTEw(shortened)">
```

However, the image doesn't display.

Comment: I'm no javascript expert, but it seems that if ``dataToString`` contains the JPEG file (as per the JFIF information), then the problem must be in the image base64 conversion. I think you the ``encodeURI`` call is unnecessary, because ``btoa`` will take the binary and covert to base64. Also, in the places I looked, there is a space between the comma after "base64" and the base64 encoded image.

Comment: Hi @RasmusW, thanks for the reply. If you could please have a look at my Edit 1, I've explained in detail the reason why the `encodeURI`.

Comment: *I do apologize that this is a very specific question* No need to apologize - being specific is actually a good thing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a base64 encoded representation of the image. This isn't simply the binary data converted to a string.

In order to get this to work, you need to tell Angular to expect a Blob using the [`responseType`](https://angular.io/api/http/ResponseContentType) parameter. This lets it know not to attempt to parse it as JSON. You convert that blob into a data URI.

There are several explanations of how this works (with examples) on Stack Overflow:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/45722275/105518
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/40862839/105518
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47002145/105518