# Get user photo from graphapi and set it as profile picture in Angular application

Tags: angular, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to set profile picture using graph API. Here is the service

```
  readdetails():Observable<any>{   
    return this.http.get<any>('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo');
  }
```

So I am getting the JSON without much issue and here is how it looks

```
{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('69sdf57b-f186-4007-b481-438fd5a870d3')/photo/$entity","@odata.mediaContentType":"image/jpeg","@odata.mediaEtag":"\"F52AEF83\"","id":"648X648","height":648,"width":648}
```

But I have no idea, how to use this information to set as src of my image in component

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the response, you need a base64 encoded representation of the image. You need to tell Angular to expect a Blob using the [**responseType**](https://angular.io/api/http/ResponseContentType) parameter.

Check this answer for more [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45720756/angular4-show-image-from-server/45722275#45722275)