# 416 (Requested Range Not Satisfiable) HTTP error when using a blob as the video "src"

Tags: angular, html5-video, blob, angular-cli, http-error

I created an object url with a blob

```
let src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
```

and used it as my video `src` attribute, but it causes this error:

```
GET blob:http://localhost:4200/ab3cc5aa-19cc-41f1-a4b7-55e1fa3ce85c 416 (Requested Range Not Satisfiable)
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

---

Although I think my problem is general, I'm using angular 2, so precisely, my code looks like this:

```
let src = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
```

and the template

```
<video *ngFor="let videoUrl of _videos" [src]="videoUrl"></video>
```

Also, I'm using angular-cli as my server, and since this looks like a server error (?), it might be useful to know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39734409/angular2-and-window-url-createobjecturl . it appears that `bypassSecurityTrustUrl` is unneeded here.

Comment: Have you tried setting video.srcObject using the blob directly?

Comment: @K3N nobody does support that yet, unfortunately... `srcObject` is still limited to MediaStreams

Comment: Where does this Blob comes from? This error often comes out when you try to pass an empty file. Has your blob a `size`?

Comment: @estus Not a duplicate and `bypassSecurityTrustUrl` is needed, both in my case and in the question you linked.

Comment: @Kaiido You are right! My blob was empty. I fixed my code to have a non-empty blob and now it works. Please post this as an answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error means that the browser tried to get a range of the media that doesn't exist.
I can think of three ways that could have trigger it from a Media Element :

- use the `#t=` timerange option, with an out of range value: *But browsers seems to just ignore it in this case...*

  ```html
  <video src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/bch2j17v6ny4ako/movie720p.mp4#t=90000,100000" autoplay controls></video>
  ```
- Remove the file while it is currently being read (or revoke the blobURI of a blob before it's get completely loaded): *That triggers a 404 not a 416*

  ```js
  v.onloadedmetadata = e => {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(v.src);
    v.currentTime = 300;
    };
  fetch('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/bch2j17v6ny4ako/movie720p.mp4').then(r=>r.blob()).then(b=>{
    v.src = URL.createObjectURL(b);
    })
  ```

  ```html
  <video id="v" autoplay></video>
  ```
- Wrong metadata stating that the media's duration is greater than what it is really: *I didn't tested it yet*
- Pass an empty Blob as the media source: **That's probably it**

  ```js
  v.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([], {type:'video/mp4'}));
  ```

  ```html
  <video id="v" autoplay controls></video>
  ```

**[Note]** Since we are looking for network errors, please try the above snippets with your dev-tools console open, there is no way to show these errors directly in the snippet's console.