# Angular2 Displaying PDF

Tags: pdf, angular, asp.net-web-api, filestream

I have an angular2 project with an ASP.Net Web API. I have code to retrieve a file path from my database which goes to a document on my server. I then want to display this document in the browser in a new tab. Does anybody have any suggestions how to do this?

I am happy to retrieve the file in either Angular2 (Typescript) or in my API and stream it down.

This is my attempt of retrieving it in my API but i cannot work out how to receive it in Angular2 and display it properly:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetSOP(string partnum, string description)
    {
        var sopPath = _uow.EpicorService.GetSOP(partnum, description).Path;
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var stream = new FileStream(sopPath, FileMode.Open);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        return result;
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks!!!

Comment: If you want to see it in another tab, why not just open a new tab to the API's URL and let the browser interpret the content? You'd probably need to use a mime type of "application/pdf" instead of "application/octet-stream".

Comment: I wrote about getting and displaying pdf files in new tab in Angular 2 here, check out my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046133/pdf-blob-is-not-showing-content-angular-2/39657478#39657478

Comment: @StefanSvrkota would this work with my API as it is? Or would i need to make changes to return it in the right format?

Comment: I'm not sure, try it. I can let you know later how my API looks.

Comment: OK im just implementing it and ill let you know :)

Comment: any update on this? i see a anwer got accepted?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

First of all, you need to set options for your http request - set `responseType` to `ResponseContentType.Blob`, use `blob()` to read response as `blob` and set its type to `application/pdf`:

```
downloadPDF(): any {
    return this._http.get(url, { responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob }).map(
    (res) => {
            return new Blob([res.blob()], { type: 'application/pdf' })
        }
}
```

Then, in order to get the file, you need to `subscribe` to it and you can create new `ObjectURL` and use `window.open()` to open PDF in new tab:

```
this.myService.downloadPDF().subscribe(
        (res) => {
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(res);
        window.open(fileURL);
        }
    );
```

Comment: Hi,Stefan.It is showing me failed to to load PDF document.Please help me.I am using Angular4.

Comment: I could able to download but not able to show in the new browser tab.

Comment: `return new Blob([res.blob()]` saved my day, Thanks

Comment: Be careful if you're using an ad-blocker extension. Ad-blockers block blob URLs by default. As a result, e.g. in Chrome and Firefox, with the uBlock Origin extension, it would try to open the new window and close it automatically. You can read more about here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51272781/why-do-ad-blockers-block-blobs

Comment: Also, if you care about this working in IE too, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007073/open-links-made-by-createobjecturl-in-ie11

Answer (score 14):

**Angular v.5.2.1 answer:**

*In `*.services.ts`*

```
downloadPDF(): any {
    return this._httpClient.get(url, { responseType: 'blob'})
            .map(res => {
            return new Blob([res], { type: 'application/pdf', });
        });
  }
```

*And then in `*.component.ts`*

```
downloadPDF() {
    let tab = window.open();
    this._getPdfService
      .downloadPDF()
      .subscribe(data => {
        const fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(data);
        tab.location.href = fileUrl;
      });
  }
```

Its important to initiate and open a new tab **before** calling the service. Then set this tabs url to the fileurl.

Comment: why is important to open the tab before calling the service instead of opening it with the objecturl as parameter (as shown in the selected answer)?

Comment: @PauFracés because you're not 'allowed' to open a tab "programatically", only users are allowed to open tabs, thus you must initiate a new tab as close as possible to the user interaction which happens when a user click on a button which then calls `downloadPDF()`. Inside the subscription is too far from the user interaction.

Comment: I'm getting Error
Failed to load PDF document.

Comment: @jonas Can you take a look at this question. I have a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55070184/download-pdf-automatically-after-getting-file-path-string-from-api-call

Answer (score 5):

**ANGULAR 5**

I had the same problem which I lost few days on that.

Here my answer may help others, which helped to render pdf.

For me even though if i mention as responseType : 'arraybuffer', it was unable to take it.

For that you need to mention as responseType : 'arraybuffer' as 'json'.([Reference](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586))

Working code

**service.ts**

```
downloadPDF(): any {
return this._httpClient.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' as 'json' })
        .map(res => {
        return new Blob([res], { type: 'application/pdf', });
    });
```

}

**component.ts**

```
this.myService.downloadPDF().subscribe(
    (res) => {
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(res);
    window.open(fileURL);
    }
);
```

Referred from the below link

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586

Comment: How do I change it for my service call? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55070184/download-pdf-automatically-after-getting-file-path-string-from-api-call

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2+ Example PDF-viewer

Page.html

```
<div class="container">
<div>
    <label>PDF src</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="PDF src" [(ngModel)]="pdfSrc">
</div>
<div>
    <label>Page:</label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Page" [(ngModel)]="page">
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="thumbnail" style="width: 150px;height: 200px;" (click)="pdfShow=!pdfShow">
            <p>click me to view PDF in Iframe!</p>
            <pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSrc"
                        [page]="page"
                        [original-size]="false"
                        style="display: block;"
             ></pdf-viewer>
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div *ngIf="!pdfShow">
            <h4>PDF in Iframe</h4>
            <iframe width="500" height="600" [src]="pageurl" type="application/pdf"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<h2> PDF in Object Tag</h2>
<object width="500" height="600"  data="https://vadimdez.github.io/ng2-pdf-viewer/pdf-test.pdf" type="application/pdf"></object>
```

page.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform- 
browser'

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
 })
 export class AppComponent {

  pdfSrc = 'https://vadimdez.github.io/ng2-pdf-viewer/pdf-test.pdf';
  page: number = 1;
  pageurl: SafeResourceUrl;

  constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
     }
      ngOnInit() {
      this.pageurl = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.pdfSrc);
     }
     title = 'Mohsen';
     }
```

app.module.ts

add

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 
import { PdfViewerComponent } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';.
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

import the

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
],
```