# Spring boot Angular2 file download not working

Tags: spring, rest, angular, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I am having a problem with dowloading file from spring boot with angular2.

Here is my code from spring boot, it came from: [Return generated pdf using spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652760/return-generated-pdf-using-spring-mvc). I can download file dirrectly with postman but not with angular2...

```
@RequestMapping(value="/file/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getFile(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    UploadFile uFile = uploadFileService.getUploadFileById(id);


    byte[] contents = uFile.getContent();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
    headers.setContentDispositionFormData(uFile.getName(), uFile.getName());
    headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(contents, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Angular2 service

```
downloadFile( id: number ){
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/pdf', 'Accept': 'application/pdf'});
    headers.append('Authorization',this.auth.token);
    let options = new RequestOptions( { headers: headers, responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob});

    return this.http.get(this.editUrl + id, options)
    .map(res => {return new Blob([res.blob()],{ type: 'application/pdf' })});
}
```

And download button

```
downloadFile(uFile: UploadFile){
    this.uploadFileService.downloadFile(uFile.id)
        .subscribe(
                data => window.open(URL.createObjectURL(data)),
            );
    return false;
}
```

When I click download button chrome opens new tab and immediately closes it not showing any file.
And here are some response headers from postman.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers →Content-Type, x-requested-with, Authorization, responseType
Access-Control-Allow-Methods →POST, PUT, GET, PATCH, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Max-Age →3600
Cache-Control →must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Content-Disposition →form-data; name="reference.pdf"; filename="reference.pdf"
Content-Length →31576
Content-Type →application/pdf
Date →Mon, 27 Mar 2017 08:39:24 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options →nosniff
X-Frame-Options →DENY
X-XSS-Protection →1; mode=block
```

Comment: Check out these two answers, I wrote about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046133/pdf-blob-is-not-showing-content-angular-2/39657478#39657478 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40300252/angular2-displaying-pdf/40300966#40300966

Comment: Yes those are exactly codes that I used in my solution but problem still occurs. When i try to download file in IE it opens new tab whit link something like: blob:8ASDA017-7456B-4614-AD56-47456456021

Comment: It doesn't work in IE, only in Chrome and Mozilla as far as i know.

Comment: Oh my god you are right. I have just installed firefox and it is working fine. It is not working in my chrome. And my IE is showing: Some content or files on this webpage require a program that you don't have installed. so many hours of fixing problem that never existed....

Comment: It is working in Chrome 100%, try updating to latest version.

Comment: Yes I have found a solution for my problem. Adblock plugin was blocking it.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring boot solution was based on [Return generated pdf using spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652760/return-generated-pdf-using-spring-mvc) and Angular2 on   [PDF Blob is not showing content, Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046133/pdf-blob-is-not-showing-content-angular-2/39657478#39657478). Code in question is completly working. **The reason of tab auto-closing with pdf file is Adblock plugin in chrome.**