# Save a PDF generated by SpringBoot in Angular

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I am trying to save a PDF using Angular and Spring Boot.

When I make an API call, my Java code is fetching the data from the database and transforming it to a byte-stream. This stream is sent as response.

```java
if(format.equals(Constant.PDF_FORMAT)) {
    ByteArrayInputStream stream = reportPDF.generateReportDocument(dtos);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=report.pdf");
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
                         .headers(headers)
                         .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
                         .body(new InputStreamResource(stream));
}
```

I have to use this response and save the data into a PDF.

#### Component.ts

```
public getReports(type?: string): void {
    this.params['expected-format'] = type;

    if (type === 'json') {
      this.Service.getPilotReports(this.params).subscribe((res) => {
        this.reportsData = res;
        this.pilotBankSpinnerService.closeSpinner();
      });
    } else {
      this.Service.customGetForDownload(this.params).subscribe(
        (data: Blob) => {
          var file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
          var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
          window.open(fileURL);
          var a = document.createElement('a');
          a.href = fileURL;
          a.target = '_blank';
          a.download = 'reports.pdf';
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.click();          
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log('getPDF error: ', error);
         
        }
      );
    }
}
```

#### Service.ts

```
public customGetForDownload<blob, T>(url: string, params: any): any {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', responseType: 'blob' });
    const httpParams = this.http.constructParams(params);
    const absoluteUrl = this.getAbsoluteUrl(url);
    return this.httpClient.get(absoluteUrl, {
      headers: headers,
      params: httpParams,
      responseType: 'blob' as 'json',
      observe: 'response',
    });
}
```

Though the file is getting saved. When I try to open the file, it says "Failed to load pdf document".

Comment: And where is `customGetForDownload` called?

Comment: Most likely not properly closed stream, you need to test pdf generating separately and concentrate on relevant parts.

Comment: @eol i have updated my post, customGetForDownload is getting called in my component file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Syntax Issues

First I see a syntax error:

- missing argument in method-call: `ByteArrayInputStream stream = reportPDF.generateReportDocument(dtos, );` (after the comma)

With this syntax error you most likely receive a compilation-error on console.

Assume this is a lapse and you can fix it to something like `ByteArrayInputStream stream = reportPDF.generateReportDocument(dtos);` then it should compile.

### Boots without errors? Then test the endpoint!

Assume further your server application boots and runs without errors, then you could test the HTTP-endpoint with a HTTP-call.

You can test using a HTTP-client like CURL, postman or maybe even a browser.

Then you should receive a response with HTTP status code 200 and the body containing the PDF-file as binary with MIME-type `application/pdf` and specified header [`Content-Dispositon`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition).

The browser is expected to prompt you with a download-dialogue.

### Responding with a binary in Spring

Your `InputStreamResource` is a valid way, but you should be confident when using it.

In a Spring controller method, you can return the binary data in different types:

- `ResponseEntity<byte[]>` as byte-array
- `ResponseEntity<ByteArrayOutputStream>` as stream (not input-stream for reading input)
- `ResponseEntity<Resource>` as abstract binary content, see Spring's [`Resource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html)
- `ResponseEntity<File>` as entire file

See also

- [Spring boot Angular2 file download not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043325/spring-boot-angular2-file-download-not-working)
- [PDF Blob is not showing content, Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046133/pdf-blob-is-not-showing-content-angular-2/39657478#39657478)
- [Return generated pdf using spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652760/return-generated-pdf-using-spring-mvc)

There are also some response-directed ways especially in Spring:

- return a `InputStreamResource` as you did
- return a `StreamingResponseBody` is very convenient
- write to a `HttpServletResponse`, probably the oldest way

See: [How To Download A File Directly From URL In Spring Boot](https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/How-To-Download-A-File-Directly-From-URL-In-Spring-Boot/)

### From input to output

Remember: Input is for reading (e.g. from a request), output is for writing (e.g. to a response). So you need an output type, like `byte[]` or `ByteArrayOutputStream` etc for your response-body.

When reading input into `ByteArrayInputStream stream` you could copy from that input to an output-stream with e.g. Apache-Commons [IOUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html): `IOUtils.copy(in, out);`.
Or simply return the byte-array: `byte[] data = stream.readAllBytes();`

See: [Java InputStream to Byte Array and ByteBuffer | Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/convert-input-stream-to-array-of-bytes)

Comment: I just checked the api with Spring Seperaytely via postman, and i was able to download the pdf and view it without any exceptions

Comment: @LuciferGeralt Thans, glad to hear you solved and tested it successfully. Next time adding the compiler-error or any console output to your question would help us to spot and solve the issue ️