# Open pdf from bytes array in angular 5

Tags: pdf, angular5

I was following the below links for displaying pdf page in new tab in my angular 5 application. But unable to achieve the result.

I am consuming the bytes array from spring controller api.

[PDF Blob is not showing content, Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046133/pdf-blob-is-not-showing-content-angular-2)

[PDF Blob - Pop up window not showing content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729451/pdf-blob-pop-up-window-not-showing-content)

[Angular2 Displaying PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40300252/angular2-displaying-pdf)

I tried the below options but none of them is working.

### **Trial 1**

Consumed the response as json

component.ts

```
clickEvent(){
this.service.getPDF().subscribe((response)=>{

  let file = new Blob([response.byteString], { type: 'application/pdf' });            
  var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  window.open(fileURL);
})
```

}

service.ts

```
getPDF(){
const url = `${this.serviceUrl}/pdf`;

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders(
    {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'responseType':'blob'
    }
  )
};

return this.http.get<any>(url, httpOptions);

}
```

### **Trial 2**

Consumed the response as json

component.ts

```
clickEvent(){
this.service.getPDF().subscribe((response)=>{

  let file = new Blob([response.byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });            
  var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  window.open(fileURL);
})
```

}

service.ts

```
getPDF(){
const url = `${this.serviceUrl}/pdf`;

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders(
    {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'responseType':'arraybuffer'
    }
  )
};

return this.http.get<any>(url, httpOptions);

}
```

### **Trial 3**

Consumed the response as bytes

component.ts

```
clickEvent(){
this.service.getPDF().subscribe((response)=>{

  let file = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });            
  var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  window.open(fileURL);
})
```

}

service.ts

```
getPDF(){
const url = `${this.serviceUrl}/pdf`;

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders(
    {
      'responseType':'blob'                 //both combination
      //'responseType'  : 'arraybuffer'
    }
  )
};

return this.http.get<any>(url, httpOptions);

}
```

By all the combination I am only getting two results.
Empty pdf document or Failed to load PDF document.

[image]

[image]

For understanding posting java spring controller code.

controller.java

```
@GetMapping(value = "/pdf")
public ResTest generatePDF(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    ResTest test = new ResTest();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = docTypeService.createPdf();
    test.setByteArray(baos.toByteArray());
    test.setByteString(new String(baos.toByteArray()));
    return test;
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

At last, I was able to render pdf. There were two small mistakes from my side.

1 st Problem was, I gave 'responseType' inside HttpHeaders which was wrong.
It should be outside as below.

2 nd Problem was, even though if you mention as responseType : 'arraybuffer', it was unable to take it. For that you need to mention as responseType : 'arraybuffer' as 'json'.([Reference](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586))

The corrected and working code below.

**Trial 3**

component.ts  (nochanges)

```
clickEvent(){
  this.service.getPDF().subscribe((response)=>{

  let file = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' });            
  var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  window.open(fileURL);
})
```

service.ts

```
getPDF(){
const url = `${this.serviceUrl}/pdf`;

const httpOptions = {
  'responseType'  : 'arraybuffer' as 'json'
   //'responseType'  : 'blob' as 'json'        //This also worked
};

return this.http.get<any>(url, httpOptions);

}
```

Referred from the below link

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586

Comment: can you help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63187758/issue-while-printing-pdf-files-from-blob-agnular

Comment: worked like charm. in the first attempt :)

Comment: Awesome, in .NET, with an IActionResult, I needed: return File(bytes, "application/pdf"); instead of returning Ok(bytes);

Comment: Awesome solution, after doing lots of researches, finally tried your solution and it worked perfectly. :) You made my day

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with angular and pdf display. I will describe my solution - use base64 encoded string. All modern browsers support base64.

1. Use `import java.util.Base64` to decode your byte array

   ```
   byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();

   String string = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);

   test.setByteString(string);
   ```
2. On the frontend side use standard mime type for pdf and indicate that you are using base64 `data:application/pdf;base64,`.

   Ref. to mime types: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type

   If you need to open document in a new window:

   ```
   let newPdfWindow = window.open("","Print");

   let content = encodeURIComponent(response.byteString);

   let iframeStart = "<\iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/pdf;base64, ";

   let iframeEnd = "'><\/iframe>";

   newPdfWindow.document.write(iframeStart + content + iframeEnd);
   ```
3. If you need to open in a new tab, you may simply provide to your html href:

   ```
   let pdfHref = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + content);
   ```

   `bypassSecurityTrustUrl` will sanitize your url. As I remember there was some problem with angular security, that prevented me from seeing the content.

PS. before checking how it works with angular I would like to recommend you to store the pdf file on a drive and try to open it. I mean, that you should be certainly sure that you file is valid and you may open it with simple reader.

Update. The simpliest solution is to use pdf.js library https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Comment: This only works because you're using an IFrame. Chrome removed top-level support for data URI's [over a year ago](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/GbVcuwg_QjM/GsIAQlemBQAJ).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63187758/issue-while-printing-pdf-files-from-blob-agnular can you solve this

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked for an angular component to wrap pdf.js?

- https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer

Sample usage:

```
<pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSrc" 
    [render-text]="true"
    style="display: block;">
</pdf-viewer>
```

`pdfSrc` can be a url `string` or a `UInt8Array`

Answer (score 0):

**When you make AJAX call to get PDF/file stream**

```
var req = this.getYourPDFRequest(fd);
    this.postData(environment.previewPDFRFR, req).then(res => {
      res.blob().then(blob => {
         const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.open(fileURL, '', 'height=650,width=840');
      })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If ur byte array comes from a .net backend u have to return

`return File(doc.BinaryData, "application/pdf");`  // page visible in typescript

, and not this :

`return Ok(doc.BinaryData);` // page blank in typescript