# How to open a PDF file from API response into HTML iframe using Angular

Tags: pdf, iframe, blob

I am trying to load a PDF doc that I am getting from API response in Blob format into iframe src in HTML , but receiving a empty document after loading. Below is the code I have tried. I am not sure why the contents of the PDF is not loading, just getting a blank empty PDF document. Am I missing something? Any help is much appreciated.

```
 <div id="my-container" class="ng-scope pdfobject-container">
                    <iframe src="" title= "" id="framContainer" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="auto" style="overflow: auto;">
                    </iframe>
                </div>

 this.conditionsService.sendToLender(payload, "1111133333").subscribe((response: any) => {
      
     let file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});

     let fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      if(fileURL) {
        const el = document.querySelector("iframe");
        if (!el) {
          throw new ReferenceError("File not found");
      }
      el.src = fileURL;
            }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: NVM, this solution worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50260391/open-pdf-from-bytes-array-in-angular-5?rq=2