# Download PDF automatically after getting file path string from api call

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I have this code snippet that returns a string that is a path to a pdf file. I was wondering, instead of returning just the string, can I get it to automatically download the pdf in the browser after I make this call? If so, how?

```
getMergedPDF(filesToUpload: Array<string>) {
    return this.http.post<string>('http://localhost:8080/merge-pdf', filesToUpload)
    .subscribe(data  => this.mergedUrl = data);
  }
```

Where string returned above is a file path:  `/Users/foo/Documents/PDFMerger/PDFMerger/server/test-pdfs/merged-pdf.pdf`

EDIT: When I try the solutions below, the file fails to load.

Comment: Hi. I came her by your request. I'm not sure why your solution doesn't work, but if I must guess thats because you don' have any servers serving your pdf file? If you so should change your url from 'localhost:4200/.../' to 'file://users/.../'. If I were you I would try to let ng serve host and serve my pdf file. Put it inside an assets folder inside your angular project. The url should then look something like 'localhost:4200/assets/merge-pdf.pdf'. This would be a first step approach just to make sure your typescript code is getting the file correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You would have something like:

```
.subscribe(data  => {
  var dl = document.createElement('a');
  dl.setAttribute('href', data);
  dl.setAttribute('download', 'pdfname.pdf');
  document.body.appendChild(dl);
  dl.click();
  document.body.removeChild(dl);
});
```

Comment: What is "a" here?

Comment: The HTML anchor tag

Comment: Should appendChild(a) be appendChild(dl) instead?

Comment: Also it seems like you're close but it returns a file on path:  localhost:4200/(filepath-i-specify-above) which it doesn't find.

Comment: Edited. And you would need to have relative file paths for this to work.

Comment: What do you mean by that? So data in this example would be something like "/Users/foo/Documents/PDFMerger/PDFMerger/server/test-pdfs/pdf-sample.pdf"and while the functionality works, it says "failed - no file" so something doesn't get set properly.

Comment: Are you able to actually download the file if you access http://localhost:8080/Users/foo/Documents/PDFMerger/PDFMerger/server/test-pdfs/merged-pdf.pdf ?

Comment: @KevinDoyon No, I get a 404. The file is on my drive inside the folder in my project actually.

Comment: ok well that means the Angular code is fine, it's just that the string returned by `http://localhost:8080/merge-pdf`is wrong?

Comment: @KevinDoyon that's the endpoint url though. I mergedUrl I get back is a url pointing to my local drive.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
            getMergedPDF(filesToUpload: Array<string>) {
    return this.http.post<string>('http://localhost:8080/merge-pdf', filesToUpload)
    .subscribe(data  => {
             this.mergedUrl = data;
             this.getPDF(this.mergedUrl);});
getPDF(uri){
this.http.get(uri, { responseType: 'blob' }) .subscribe(x=>{

            var newBlob = new Blob([x], { type: "application/pdf" });

           //IE Fix
            if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(newBlob);
                return;
            }
            const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = data;
            link.download = "merge.pdf";
            link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window }));

            setTimeout(function () {
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data);
                link.remove();
            }, 100);
        });
```

Comment: ReferenceError: x is not defined

Comment: You are getting a link back not the object. I have modified my answer. now it should work

Comment: I get this error: HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4200/Users/~/Documents/PDFMerger/PDFMerger/server/test-pdfs/merged-pdf.pdf", ok: false, …}