# Saving a ZIP File from AJAX Response in Angular 2/TypeScript

Tags: ajax, angular, typescript, download

I am trying to download a zip fie which is returned as binary in the response of a AJAX Request.

I tried the following code but was not able to download it and even if I downloaded it the file got corrupted. I checked whether the response is correct and went to the network tab in developer tool and saved the response as a zip file and opened it, and it was successfully opened.
Hopefully someone can tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
  var URL = window.URL;

  var downloadData = new Blob([data._body], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });

  var downloadURL = URL.createObjectURL(downloadData);

  window.open(downloadURL);
```

the browser openes up a new window and tells me the file is not supported in IE & downloads a corrupted file in Chrome. The URL in browser is something like

```
blob:http://localhost:4200/62b8283c-1391-4133-98a4-ed3cc9aa1f73
```

-

```
      var downloadData = new Blob([data._body], { type: 'application/zip' });

  FileSaver.saveAs(downloadData,"hi.zip");
```

The above code does not give any specific errors but when the file is saved it is corrupted.
I also tried the above code with type as `application/octet-stream` but that has the same result.

Thing is the binary data seems to be perfectly fine, the only thing I need to do is open a save dialog which will save the binary data. Seems to be a pretty simple usecase, but seems to be a bit confusing in case of zip in the Js/TS side.
I think the main issue is that I am creating a blob with the binary data(which I don't think I need to or should be transforming to a blob) but I was not able to trigger the download without creating a blob object as the APIs seem to be accepting only blob(like the URL Object or FileSaver API).

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046133/pdf-blob-is-not-showing-content-angular-2/39657478#39657478

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, the zip file was corrupt when I was trying to open it.
I fixed it by adding: responseType = ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer

Here is my code:

```
public httpRequest(call) {
call.headers = new Headers({
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token'),
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/octet-stream'
});

let req = new Request(call);
req.responseType = ResponseContentType.ArrayBuffer;

return this.http.request(req).map((res: Response) => {
  return res;
});
```

}

make sure you imported:

```
import { Http, Headers, Request, Response, BaseResponseOptions, ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';
```