# PDF from REST API not loading into Angular 2 app

Tags: angular, pdf, typescript

**What specific changes need to be made to the below in order for an Angular 2 / 4 app to successfully load a PDF file from a RESTful http call into the web browser?**

Note that the app in question extends http to add a JWT to http requests.  According to [this link](https://github.com/cornflourblue/mean-angular2-registration-login-example/blob/master/client/app/_helpers/custom-http.ts), extending http in this way will cause problems related to overriding RequestOptions.

---

**THE SPECIFICS**:

---

The intended PDF is successfully served by a backend API when users type `http://192.168.1.5:4000/whitepaper.pdf` into a web browser.  However, the Angular app needs to absorb the white paper from the API programattically, and then serve the pdf in the browser with a url that is part of the Angular app.

The code for the Angular app is as follows:

**my.service.ts**

```
getAll() {
    console.log('Inside getAll!');
    return this.http.get('http://192.168.1.5:4000/whitepaper.pdf').map((response: Response) => response.blob())
            .catch((err:Response) => {
        console.log('Error block!');
        return Observable.throw('error!');
     });;
}
```

**my.component.ts**

```
getPDF() {
    console.log('Hey there, Jackass!');
    console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).token);
    let myblob = new Blob([this.pDFService.getAll()], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    console.log(myblob.type);
    console.log(myblob.size);
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(myblob);
    window.open(fileURL); // if you want to open it in new tab
}
```

`myblob.type` prints out as `application/pdf`, and `myblob.size` prints out as `15`.

The backend API is in Node.js/Express.

The Angular code sample is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046133/pdf-blob-is-not-showing-content-angular-2#39657478), but does not work in the present situation.

The Code for the `custom-http.ts` is at [this link](https://github.com/cornflourblue/mean-angular2-registration-login-example/blob/master/client/app/_helpers/custom-http.ts) .  The link mentions that problems will occur in the present circumstances when http is overridden as it is in the present app.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getAll()` is returning you an `Observable`. Thus :

```
    this.pDFService.getAll().subscribe( data => {
        let myblob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(myblob);
        window.open(fileURL); // if you want to open it in new tab
    })
```