# Open PDF blob from Angular Component

Tags: angular, pdf, blob

In my Angular application, I need to open a PDF when a button is clicked.

I followed the directions given by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046133/pdf-blob-is-not-showing-content-angular-2) post in the first place, so I have these two methods right now:

**In the calling component**

```
public PrepareDownload(){
   this._certificateService
            .GetPdf(args)
            .subscribe(
            result => {
                this.BlobUri = URL.createObjectURL(result);
            }
}

public Download() {
    window.open(this.BlobUri);     
}
```

**In the service**

```
public GetPdf() : any  {
  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
  var payload = {id:215};
  return this._http.post(this.requestUri, 
                         JSON.stringify(payload), 
                         { headers: headers, 
                           responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob })
                   .map((response: Response) => 
                   {
                      return new Blob([response.blob()], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                   });
}
```

GetPdf's response contains an array like the following `[ 37,80,68,70,45,49,46,...]`. Unfortunately, when the download method is called, the result seems to be an invalid pdf. When downloading the file via firefox and renaming it to a txt-file, I can see that the content is not binary but the complete byte array as a string.

[image]

Comment: I don't think rewrapping the blob is necessary, `(response: Response) => response.blob()` typically worked for me.

Comment: when not adding the type headers, the browser won't even try to open this with a pdf viewer. To add these headers, i re-wrap.

Comment: Well, make sure the server returns correct Content-Type in a first place.

Comment: That was a good hint. I adapted my server code to return a stream rather than a byte array. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the comments by @David Siro, The Service had to be modified. 
The request now returns a stream rather than a byte array, which can be handled as described in the question.