# Angular 4, display pdf in current tab

Tags: angular

In my angular 4 application I want to display a PDF, I found this good way:
[PDF Blob is not showing content, Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046133/pdf-blob-is-not-showing-content-angular-2/39657478#39657478)

But in this way I open a new tab in the browser and for example in my case this new popup was blocked by adblock. 
So there is a way to show the PDF in the current tab? And something to avoid adblock?

**Component.ts**

```
print() {
    this.ticketBundleService.downloadPDF().subscribe(
      (res) => {
        const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(res);
        window.open(fileURL);
      }
    );
  }
```

**Service.ts**

```
  downloadPDF(): any {
    return this.http.get('http://......', {responseType: 'blob'}).map(
      (res) => {
        return new Blob([res], {type: 'application/pdf'})
      })
  }
```

Comment: try to download on same page. i.e. 1) create link, 2) click link, 3) remove link