# Post complex data using ajax and open returned PDF in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax, pdf

I need to use JQuery ajax to post a complex and sensitive data object (nested objects, arrays, and Personally Identifiable Information) to my server, where a PDF is generated and returned to the client. The client browser then should open the PDF in a new window.

Because of the nature of the data the request neither can nor should be an encoded URL - it must include the data as a JSON body.

The other questions/answers on this subject did not solve the problem in my case or do not do so completely.

Comment: See also [How to build PDF file from binary string returned from a web-service using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876000/how-to-build-pdf-file-from-binary-string-returned-from-a-web-service-using-javas/), [jquery-ajax-blob-arraybuffer.js](https://gist.github.com/SaneMethod/7548768)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution**

1. POST with the data in the body as JSON.
2. Set the expected `Content-Type` of the response to `arraybuffer` (on the client and server).
3. When the request has complete successfully, convert the response to a `Blob`.
4. Create an object url to the `Blob` and open it in a new window.

**Notes**

- JQuery ajax [does not support](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11461) the `arraybuffer` `Content-Type` so the base JavaScript `xhr` must be used (if you don't have any other options).
- Internet Explorer has its own functionality for handling and displaying `Blob`'s, so a special case is needed.
- [Supported browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) does not include IE9

**Code**

```js
RequestPdf = function (url, data) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest(), file, fileURL;
    request.open("POST", url);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    request.send(data);
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
            file = new Blob([request.response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
            if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) { // IE
                window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file);
            } else {
                fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                window.open(fileURL);
            }
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: What is purpose of setting `.responseType` to `"arraybuffer"` where `ArrayBuffer` is then converted to `Blob`?

Comment: `createObjectUrl` only takes a `Blob` (or a `File`) as an input parameter. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

Comment: _"where a PDF is generated and returned to the client"_ If server reponds with `content-type:application/pdf` header `.responseType = "blob"`  could be used? Does response not have `content-type:application/pdf` header set?

Comment: the response actually has `content-type:arraybuffer` set. I have not tried to set it directly to `blob`, though. Your suggestion might be a more direct solution to that aspect of the problem.