# How to get PDF downloaded in $resource put service angularjs1

Tags: angularjs, put

I want to download a PDF from server depending on the input request sent from UI . I am getting a pop-up with [object objcet] written on it .
Can somebody help me out in this . 
P.S. : I have to use $resource only , not the $http one , thanks :)

This is my Service call to WEB API , Service name is "GetInvoice"-->

```
function ($resource) {
    return $resource('app/rest/invoice/:id', null, {
             'update': { method:'PUT'}
        },{ headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'}, 
    transformRequest: []});
                     }
```

This is my service call from controller -->

```
GetInvoice.update({id:'1'},angular.toJson(invoiceJSON)).$promise.then(function (data) { 

          var file = new Blob([data]);
          var fileURL = ($window.URL || $window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(file);
          $window.open(fileURL, '_blank', 'download');});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line

```
var file = new Blob([data]);
```

to

```
var file = new Blob([data.data]);
```

and check out.

If this doesn't work out,

dynamically create a anchor tag and invoke the click event which will open a popup / new tab with the content. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30405383/4226224)

Comment: Hi Naveen, thanks for your help . In the URL you shared, 'responseType' is mentioned at 2nd place after API URL as its a 'get' service . How to do this in 'put' request ?

Comment: actually my error seems to be in 'data' in controller class . I am not getting appropriate value in this . It could be because I am not handling response properly in service class .

Comment: Yes. put a break point in the debugger and then watch it to see the data. [Object object] actually seems that you are working with the object and not with the data inside it. mark the answer are correct if this works out for you.