# Angular save download file

Tags: php, angular, download

I'm writing a web-app with angular frontend and php backend in angular facing the challenge now, when trying to download a file it is loaded completely by the following script.

**Angular** service:

```
downloadFile(f:string){    
    this.http.post('/api/download.php', JSON.stringify({"file": f}), {responseType:'arraybuffer'})
    .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

Used imports:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

The **PHP** file looks like this (works fine):

```
  include "config/var.inc.php";
  $dir = "../" . DATA_FOLDER . "/";
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
  $file = $dir . $data->file;

  if(file_exists($file)){
    header('Content-Description: download audio');
    header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
  }
```

The `console.log` shows me the file is completely loaded (23300766 Bytes) 
[image]

How can I deliver it to the user as a download file?

Comment: Please provide screenshot of the console for possible solutions.

Comment: Log is attached

Comment: Try this > https://stackoverflow.com/a/21730535/5116121 . You will need to change the part `type: 'application/pdf'` to your expected content-type, which seems to be `audio/mpeg` .

Comment: The problem on that solution is it'll open the file in the browser instead of downloading it.

Comment: Try this > https://stackoverflow.com/a/37340749/5116121

Comment: This works, but it's more a workaround than a solution. I am creating a link and clicking it?! Thank you so far.

Comment: If you would like to venture more, I'd suggest you to focus your search on how to accomplish your gaol in javascript as it's not related to Angular from this point on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **file-saver** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver)

This is my piece of code:

```
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';

downloadTemplate(filePath: string) { // Example: filePath = '/file-path/download.docx'
    this.http.post(`http://endpoint/download`, filePath, { observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob' })
        .subscribe((response) => {
            this.saveFile(response);
        });
}

private saveFile(response) {
    const fileName = this.getFileNameFromHttpResponse(response);
    FileSaver.saveAs(response.body, fileName);
}

private getFileNameFromHttpResponse(httpResponse) {
    const contentDispositionHeader = httpResponse.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
    const result = contentDispositionHeader.split(';')[1].trim().split('=')[1];
    return result.replace(/"/g, '');
}
```

Note: If you want to get the **file name** from the response, you need to add this ("**Access-Control-Expose-Headers**: **Content-Disposition**") to the response header from the server.