# Download PDF from jsPDF in iOS PWA

Tags: ios, vue.js, download, progressive-web-apps, jspdf

I'm developing PWA as part of my bachelor thesis. Part of the app is generating PDF report. I'm using jsPDF to create the report and then save it via `doc.save("filename.pdf")` 
This works perfectly on any desktop browser and all android phones i've tested so far.
The bad thing comes with an iOS. 
In PWA mode the PDF is shown in window with almost no options but 'done' which return back to the app so it's not possible to save the PDF.

I've tried all `doc.output()` types and solutions based around blob and `toDataUrl()`. I've read about cordova and phoneGap but i'm not sure how exactly should it work.

I'm little worried that it's not my fault but lack of PWA support in iOS

Comment: did you ever solve this? I have the same problem with my PWA in iOS.

Comment: Sadly i did not. Even iOS 13 have this issue.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like MIME type issue. Please check if the MIME type of pdf is set correctly. iOS historically has problem with responses not having explicit MIME type.

Please refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729451/pdf-blob-pop-up-window-not-showing-content) and [this one](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/375).

It should most likely not an standalone PWA issue and should be happening in iOS + Safari as well. You can validate the same and confirm here how things works.