# WebAPI and angular JS Excel file download - file corrupted

Tags: c#, angularjs, excel, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm generating an Excel file in my WebAPI. I "store" it in a memorystream and then put in the the response as follow :

```
var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new StreamContent(ms) };

            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = projectName + ".xlsx"
            };
           // ms.Close();
            return result;
```

It looks like the server side is working correcty. If I'm writing that memorystream into a filestream, the file is created and can be open without any problem.

On angular side, how can I recreate the file when click on a button?

I tried something like this :

```
$scope.exportQuotas = function (projectName) {
    homeService.GetQuotas(projectName, $routeParams.token, $scope.selection).then(
             function (data) {
                 var dataUrl = 'data:application/octet-stream;' + data
                 var link = document.createElement('a');
                 angular.element(link)
                   .attr('href', dataUrl)
                   .attr('download', "bl.xlsx")
                   .attr('target', '_blank')
                 link.click();
             })
}
```

The file is created but when I tried to open it, it's corrupted... I've tried changing the data type to vnd.ms-excel in angular but it didn't work...
How can I get the file to be downloaded on click?

**EDIT** 
After Jorg answer, I tried the following :
What the api returns is :

```
Status Code: 200
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Tue, 02 Sep 2014 02:00:24 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Type: application/binary
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?        QzpcVXNlcnNcdHJpaGFuaC5waGFtXFByb2plY3RzXFF1b3RhUXVlcnlcUXVvdGFRdWVyeUFQSVxhcGlccXVvdGFcR2V0?=
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=O14Y0129AUG.xlsx
Content-Length: 13347
Expires: -1
```

From what I can see, it looks correct.

In client side :

```
                 var file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;' });
                 var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                 window.open(fileURL);
```

A excel file is created but it's still corrupted...

Thanks

Comment: I got mine working like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447952/angularjs-http-post-convert-binary-to-excel-file-and-download/22448640#22448640

Comment: It didn't work for me though :(  file is corrupted... also as metionned, the filename is weird...

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem. The file was OK server side, but when downloaded it became corrupt.

What solved it for me was to add `responseType: "arraybuffer"` to the server request.

Then when calling this line `var file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;' });`
The `data` variable should be of type `ArrayBuffer`, and not a string.

Comment: Could you please provide the full code as to how you added responseType: "arraybuffer" to the server request?

Comment: @Shivam657 This is how you add response type to your request:
`$http.get(url, { responseType: "arraybuffer" })`

Comment: working fro me with cache : false ,responseType: "arraybuffer",

Comment: savior @daniel thank you so much daniel i was facing this issue from last 2days

Answer (score 1):

The main issue comes from the fact that by default, XMLHttpRequest uses the default response type which is an empty String. See this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data). Your binary data are therefore not correctly handled.

When using javascript API, you need to take care of the response type for binary data. Otherwise, it will be interpreted as a String.

API like angular-file-upload (last version is currently 1.1.5) for example does not provide the possibility to set the response type of data received after an upload. I had to update the API to define the response type.