# Set an excel file as response in REST Service

Tags: angularjs, api, rest, dropwizard

I used the below example to test. REST Api works, but it gives result in stream format.
But,I expect result with file option. I used this example to ingrate with Angular JS framework.

```
@GET
  @Path("/get")
  @Produces("application/vnd.ms-excel")
  public Response getFile() {
    LOG.info("get - Function begins from here");

    File file = new File("/home/test/file.xls");

    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
    response.header("Content-Disposition",
      "attachment; filename=new-excel-file.xls");
    response.header("Content-Type","application/octet-stream");
    return response.build();

  }
```

Comment: **I have found solution here to my question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447952/angularjs-http-post-convert-binary-to-excel-file-and-download**

Answer (score 2):

application/octet-stream is defined as "arbitrary binary data" in RFC 2046, so given that the file is an excel one change `response.header("Content-Type","application/octet-stream");` for `response.header("Content-Type","application/vnd.ms-excel");`

take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508788/do-i-need-content-type-application-octet-stream-for-file-download) about octet stream mime type, might be useful, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974079/setting-mime-type-for-excel-document) about excel mime type.

Comment: Yes, thanks for quick answer. I have removed **response.header("Content-Type","application/octet-stream");** and tried,but still it does not give file save dialog box.

Comment: @user1702169 I believe the behavior of how the file is handled is by browser, not by something you can set on the server side of an API.

Comment: @th3morg sure you can, just set the `Content-Disposition` header, as in the first answer this answer links to.