# AngularJS - Open or forward $http.post application/octet-stream javascript response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf

In my AngularJS application I have to request via HTTP POST for a pdf report.
The response is an application/octet-stream, containing the pdf-file.([image: Response Header])

My angular call looks like this:

```
 $http.post($rootScope.HostPath + '/report',{ param1:value, param2:value }).
                then(function success(response) {
                    //magic should happen here :(
                },function error(response) {
                    console.log("Error Code : " + response.status );
                });
        }
```

How can I get the PDF out of this response javascript variable or is it possible to forward the response directly to the browser.

When I request with Postman or other tools, a download dialog pops up immediately. I've tried a lot of different solutions from stackoverflow but non of them are working in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you check this posts :

[AngularJS $http-post - convert binary to excel file and download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447952/angularjs-http-post-convert-binary-to-excel-file-and-download)

[AngularJS: Display blob (.pdf) in an angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628378/angularjs-display-blob-pdf-in-an-angular-app?lq=1)

i think they could be solutions of your case.

Comment: I forgot to add .data in the response.