# File not downloading express.js res.download

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, express, mean-stack

I've generated/exported a `xlsx` file using `json2xlsx` npm module and to download that file I'm using `res.download(file)` functionality of of `express.js`.

Reference: [Download a file from NodeJS Server using Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288814/download-a-file-from-nodejs-server-using-express)

Following is my code:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var json2xls = require('json2xls');

app.use(json2xls.middleware);

app.get('/export/:id', function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    db.collection('provider').findOne({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)}, function (err, doc) {
        var jsonArr = {};
        var arr = jsonArr = doc;
        var xls = json2xls(arr);
        fs.writeFileSync('data.xlsx', xls, 'binary'); //file exported

        //Now I want to download that file
        res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=data.xlsx');
        res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        res.download(__dirname + '/public/data.xlsx', function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });

        //res.json(doc);
    });
});
```

View html

```
        <div class="panel-body">

            <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="(key,value) in providerList"  ng-if="!$first">                    
                    <label>{{key.replace("_", " ") | uppercase}}</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Enter Title" ng-model="providerList[key]">                    
            </div>

            <div class="well well-lg text-center bg-gray">                                        
                <button class="btn-lg btn-success" ng-click="export(id)">Export to Spreadsheet</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

AngularJS controller code:

```
$scope.export = function (id) {
            $http.put('/export/' + id, $scope.providerList).success(function (response) {
                 if (response) {
                    alert("File is successfully exported at: "+ response);
                }
            });
        };
```

Error: `{ [Error: Request aborted] code: 'ECONNABORTED' }`

**Updated Error**

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Necessary debug information. What do you mean by "not downloading"? Any errors? What will be displayed in the console with this call: `res.download(__dirname + '/data.xlsx', function(error) { console.log(error)} );` ?

Comment: This is the error: `{ [Error: Request aborted] code: 'ECONNABORTED' }`

Comment: @stdob--: Updated Post Please Check

Comment: What if you try to save a file on a temporary random name instead `data.xlsx` before sending? What show `curl -I http://you.site/export/id`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set response header before `res.download()`,

```
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=data.xlsx');
res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
res.download(__dirname + '/data.xlsx');
```

***UPDATE:***

According to [json2xls](https://github.com/rikkertkoppes/json2xls), 
you can use `res.xls('data.xlsx', jsonArr);`.

For that you have to setup middleware for json2xls

```
app.use(json2xls.middleware);
```

***UPDATE 2:***

For front end(AngularJS), Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447952/angularjs-http-post-convert-binary-to-excel-file-and-download)

Comment: data.xlsx is generating ?

Comment: Updated Post Please Check

Comment: @Mark :  I've already updated my answer and it's working, use middleware.

Comment: use res.xls('data.xlsx', jsonArr); instead of res.download(); Directly pass json array into res.xls function.

Comment: Its working now but instead excel it response is showing like above (Check updated Post) on `console & alert`

Comment: Can you update your question with client side code ?

Comment: Updated. Please check.

Comment: Refer this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447952/angularjs-http-post-convert-binary-to-excel-file-and-download

Comment: I replaced my controller's function with the code suggested in your link and its working now on chrome... Great..!!! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

May be your .xlsx file saved in the root folder.So, moved the .xlsx file under **public** folder and enable it in express like below.

```
        app.use(express.static('./public'));
```

Comment: Moved to `public` and used `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public")); // express.static means we are telling the server to look for static file i.e. html,css,js etc. but still not working
`

Comment: Here's the code now : `res.download(__dirname + '/public/data.xlsx');`

Comment: Its not showing any error but download is also not working

Comment: Updated Post Please Check

Answer (score 0):

I notice your angular controller makes a `$http.put` but your backend is expecting a GET (`app.get`). Are you sure this is how you intended to configure it?