# How to turn response to Excel file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel

I send a request to a server, then got the response, but I am not sure how to turn this response to an Excel file.

**Response header:**

```
Connection →keep-alive
cache-control →no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
content-disposition →attachment; filename=demo.xls
content-length →7680
content-type →application/vnd.ms-excel
date →Wed, 19 Sep 2018 14:40:47 GMT
expires →0
pragma →no-cache
server →Apache
x-content-type-options →nosniff
x-frame-options →DENY
x-xss-protection →1; mode=block
```

**Response data:**

> ��ࡱ�;��   �������������������������������������������������������������������RootEntry������������Workbook�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
>   ��A����\pmidadm
>   B�a=���=h:�#8X@�"��1���Arial1���Arial1���Arial1���Arial1���Calibri1���Calibri1���Calibri"$"#,##0_);("$"#,##0)"$"#,##0_);Red
>   "$"#,##0.00_);*(* "-"??*);*(@*)
>   �#.##0�   #,##0.000�[$-1009]mmmm d, yyyy;@�_($*
>
> ## ,##0.00_)��� � ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� � �
>
> �+�� �� �)�� �� �,�� �� �*�� �� � �� �� �!� �
>   � � � �"� ��#� � � ��#�
>   ��!� ��#� � #�
>   ������������������`�Demo

**Here is what I tried:**

```
var blob = new Blob([result.data], 
      {
        'type': 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
      }    
)
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.download = 'demo.xls';
document.body.appendChild(link);

link.click();
```

However, when I open the file, it has error, and cannot open it.

Any helps? Thanks,

Comment: Have you considered using a library like https://github.com/deblanco/xlsExport to handle this?

Comment: Thanks @askseli, I will check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the server response as an array buffer. Store it as a Blob using the content type from the server (which should be application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet):

```
var httpPromise = this.$http.post(server, postData, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
httpPromise.then(response => this.save(new Blob([response.data],
    { type: response.headers('Content-Type') }), fileName));
```

Save the blob to the user's device:

```
save(blob, fileName) {
    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) { // For IE:
        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
    } else { // For other browsers:
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = fileName;
        link.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33531563/2134604)

Comment: Awesome, you saved my life. The response should be an array buffer!

Comment: Cool, have fun :)