# AngularJS Display PDF (byte[]) received from Spring @RestController

Tags: angularjs, rest, spring-mvc, pdf

My my requirement is to either display(new tab)/download/embed a PDF  in my angular js app on form submit/post.

I do not want the server to return a unique identifier of the generated PDF and than use $window service to open a new window with it's url pointing to a server-side endpoint which returns PDf based on unique identifier. Because I  need to generate the pdf on the fly (no storing in file system).

Similar question to this one [AngularJS: Display blob (.pdf) in an angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628378/angularjs-display-blob-pdf-in-an-angular-app)   But it is not working for me.

**My controller**

```
angular.module('EvaluationResultsModule').controller('CA_EvaluationResultsCtrl',
    [ '$scope', 'EvaluationResultsService', '$sce', function($scope, EvaluationResultsService, $sce) {

        $scope.showPDF = function() {
            $scope.result = CA_EvaluationResultsService.getEvalutaionResultPDF($scope.evaluationResults);
            $scope.result.$promise.then(function(data) {
                var file = new Blob([data], {
                    type : 'application/pdf'
                });
                var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                $scope.pdfContent = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
            });
        }
    } ]);
```

**My Service**

```
    angular.module('EvaluationResultsModule').factory('EvaluationResultsService', function($resource) {
    return $resource('./api/ca/evaluationResults/:dest', {}, {       
        getEvalutaionResultPDF : {
            method : 'GET',
            params : {
                dest : "getPDF"
            },
            responseType : 'arraybuffer',

        }
    });
});
```

**Rest Controller Method**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getPDF", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public byte[] getEvalutaionResultPDF()  {        
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // Generate PDF using Jasper
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        List<User> usersList = null; //populated from Service layer;
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(usersList);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint =  jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("A4.jasper"), model, beanColDataSource);
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, baos);
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
```

**My response logged in console**

```
response:  Object {data: ArrayBuffer, status: 200, headers: function, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}config: Objectdata: ArrayBufferbyteLength: (...)__proto__: ArrayBufferbyteLength: [Exception: TypeError: Method ArrayBuffer.prototype.byteLength called on incompatible receiver #<ArrayBuffer>]get byteLength: function byteLength() { [native code] }constructor: function ArrayBuffer() { [native code] }slice: function slice() { [native code] }__proto__: Objectheaders: function (name) {resource: Resourcestatus: 200statusText: "OK"__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 17):

I use this code and it works for me:

REST Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/reports/pdf", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@Timed
public @ResponseBody byte[] getOpenedEventsInPdf(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=file.pdf");
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
// get file in bytearray from my custom service in backend
    byte[] file = jasperReportsService.getOpenedEventsReport(ReportFormat.PDF);
    return file;
}
```

JS/Angular Controller;

```
$scope.getPdf = function(){
  $http.get('/api/reports/pdf', {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
  .success(function (data) {
    var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    window.open(fileURL);
  });
}
```

HTML fragment:

```
<a ng-click="getPdf()">Show PDF</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for concisely answering something that took some time to find.

Comment: Thank you so much ... It worked for me with little bit changes... +1.

Comment: How to handle exceptions in Rest Controller?

Comment: Works for me too. The pdf filename is random. How can I get the filename from the setHeader `Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=file.pdf`

Comment: @Guus - you can get it from the response

`var contentDisposition = response.headers("Content-Disposition");`
`var filename = (contentDisposition.split(';')[1].trim().split('=')[1]).replace(/"/g, '');`

Comment: @amallard thank, I found also another way. Using `angular-file-saver` I can do now `FileSaver.saveAs(file, 'my_file_name.pdf');`

Answer (score 2):

> For "**Browser Compatibility**" given code is working properly :
>
> Get the byte array data from beck-end controller side and generate
>   file on js controller side **:**

**Beck-end controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getPDF", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public byte[] getEvalutaionResultPDF()  {        
        byte[] data = //get byte Array from back-end service
        return data;
}
```

**JS Service**

```
var getPdfFile = function(){
        return $http.get("getPDF", {responseType: 'arraybuffer'});
};
```

**JS controller**

```
$scope.pdfFile = function() {
        service.getPdfFile().then(function (data) {

            //for browser compatibility  
            var ieEDGE = navigator.userAgent.match(/Edge/g);
            var ie = navigator.userAgent.match(/.NET/g); // IE 11+
            var oldIE = navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/g); 
            var name = "file";
            var blob = new window.Blob([data.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });

            if (ie || oldIE || ieEDGE) {
                var fileName = name+'.pdf';
                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
            }
            else {
                var file = new Blob([ data.data ], {
                    type : 'application/pdf'
                });
                var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                var a         = document.createElement('a');
                a.href        = fileURL; 
                a.target      = '_blank';
                a.download    = name+'.pdf';
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
            }
        },
        function(error) {
            //error
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following link, you should find the answer :

[AngularJS Display PDF (byte[]) received from Spring(@RestController) + jasper report](http://aandresdev.blogspot.pe/2016/02/mostrar-pdf-en-iframe-usando-angularjs.html)

In this link you find how display pdf in a iframe using angularjs.
The pdf is received from a API rest using spring and jasper report.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please edit your question so that it contains at least a summary of what can be found at that link. Answers containing only a link, without any explanation or comment, might become useless if the link ever became invalid. Thank you!