# Rest API generated PDF byte[] JSON content-type to be viewed in Web using angularJS

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, json, pdf

I am returning a byte[] of PDF content as JSON response from REST API, and trying to render the data in angular JS.

here is my JS code snippet :

```
if(data.appStatusCode===0){                            
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data.payload);
    var reportData = jsonObj.data;                              
    var file = new Blob([reportData], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    window.open(fileURL);
 }
```

and the controller which returns byte[] as payload

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/janitramwebreport/{janitramid}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET, 
            produces = Constants.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<ResponseVO> getReportWebPdf(HttpEntity<?> httpEntity) {

    *//returns byte[] as the payload*
}
```

when I try to generate PDF in a new window, I get PDF file error message.

Comment: I changed the API to produce application/pdf and accepted at angular end as ArrayBuffer and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at:

[AngularJS: Display blob (.pdf) in an angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628378/angularjs-display-blob-pdf-in-an-angular-app)

[AngularJS Display PDF (byte[]) received from Spring @RestController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26592413/angularjs-display-pdf-byte-received-from-spring-restcontroller)

I think this has been answered already.

Comment: I have tried all those methods, but none of those works for me. I'm adding byte[] of the PDF to BO Object and sending the object to Web after changing to JSON. As you can see the response of my API is "application/json"

Answer (score -1):

In the following link, you should find the answer :

[AngularJS Display PDF (byte[]) received from Spring(@RestController) + jasper report](http://aandresdev.blogspot.pe/2016/02/mostrar-pdf-en-iframe-usando-angularjs.html)

In this link you find how display pdf in a iframe using angularjs. The pdf is received from a API rest using spring and jasper report.