# Outputting a PDF (created with FPDF) in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, fpdf

I am using FPDF to create a PDF on a Laravel backend that serves Angular. I have created it in the normal FPDF way and I am unsure how to send the file response back to Angular. 
I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628378/angularjs-display-blob-pdf-in-an-angular-app) about generall how to go about it by configuring my `$http` request as below:

```
return $http({url: '/api/print/class-list', method: "POST", data: {data: data}, headers: {'Accept':'application/pdf'}, responseType: 'arrayBuffer'})
            .then(function(response)
            {
                console.log(response.data);
                var file = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                var content = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
                return content;
            }
```

I have injected `$sce` in the service and i am outputting the `content` in an `embed` tag. The tag just shows an empty PDF. I am wondering what the problem could be. Also, on the Laravel side, once I am done creating the PDF by writing `$pdf->Output("page","D")`, is there a way i should write `return` something so that it can be returned to Angular?

Also, when i console response, it kindof returns blob or some pdf stuff, and a number of errors after that like: 
`"Warning: Unsupported feature "unknown"`

Comment: Well, i solved my problem through another approach. Still using FPDF to generate my PDF then i create a filename for the file and pass this filename(well, the full path) as first parameter of `Output()` function. The second parameter i put as "F" to make it save file to computer. After calling the function, i then return the filename to the controller and in my `object` (or `embed`) tag, i append this filename to a static relative path like `<object data="/downloads/class-lists/{{filename}}" style="width: 1000px; height: 1100px;"></object>`. It worked for me, and i just thought it could help.