# how to download a zip file

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, httpresponse, zip, pushstreamcontent

I am trying to download a zip file from my web api controller. It is returning the file but I am getting a message the zipfile is invalid when i try to open. I have seen other posts about this and the response was adding the responseType: 'arraybuffer'.  Still isn't working for me. I'm not getting any errors in the console either.

```
  var model = $scope.selection;
    var res = $http.post('/api/apiZipPipeLine/', model)

    res.success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
        saveAs(new Blob([response], { type: "application/octet-stream", responseType: 'arraybuffer' }), 'reports.zip');
            notificationFactory.success();
    });
```

api controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("ZipFileAction")]
    public HttpResponseMessage ZipFiles([FromBody]int[] id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {//Required IDs were not provided
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest));
        }

        List<Document> documents = new List<Document>();
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            foreach (int NextDocument in id)
            {
                Document document = context.Documents.Find(NextDocument);

                if (document == null)
                {
                    throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
                }

                documents.Add(document);
            }
            var streamContent = new PushStreamContent((outputStream, httpContext, transportContent) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var zipFile = new ZipFile())
                    {
                        foreach (var d in documents)
                        {
                            var dt = d.DocumentDate.ToString("y").Replace('/', '-').Replace(':', '-');
                            string fileName = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}.pdf", dt, d.PipeName, d.LocationAb);
                            zipFile.AddEntry(fileName, d.DocumentUrl);
                        }
                        zipFile.Save(outputStream); //Null Reference Exception
                    }
                }

                finally
                {
                    outputStream.Close();
                }
            });
            streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "reports.zip";

            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = streamContent
            };
            return response;
        }
    }
```

Update
[image: pic]

Comment: What's in the `saveAs` function?

Comment: it is a filesaver.js method

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you're setting the responseType in the wrong place, instead of this:

```
$http.post('/api/apiZipPipeLine/', model)
```

Try this:

```
$http.post('/api/apiZipPipeLine/', model, {responseType:'arraybuffer'})
```

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21732039/1715829) for more details.

Comment: that did work! however the pdf's are corrupt? do I need to change something in my api controller?

Comment: i posted a screenshot of a exception in my api. I know this might be a separate question but if you if you could take a look i would appreciate it

Comment: Looks like get_Length() isn't supported, perhaps you need to download the entire stream first?

Answer (score 4):

At a matter of fact you are rigth adding `responseType:'arraybuffer'`. That added to the following code when received the response from ajax will prompt a file to download:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
var blob = new Blob([responseData], {'type':"application/octet-stream"});
a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
a.download = "filename.zip";
a.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working fine for me for download zip file,

Controller

```
$scope.downloadExport = function (id,filename,frmdata) {
         frmdata = {};
        var data = tdioServices.downloadexport(id,filename,frmdata);
         data.success(function(success) {
                var blob = new Blob([success], { type:"arraybuffer" });           
                var downloadLink = angular.element('<a></a>');
                downloadLink.attr('href',window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
                downloadLink.attr('download', filename);
                downloadLink[0].click();
                $COMMON_ACCEPT = "Download Successfully";
                $COMMON_ACCEPT_TEXT = "Success";
                toastr.success($COMMON_ACCEPT, $COMMON_ACCEPT_TEXT);

        });
    };
```

Services

```
 this.downloadexport = function(id,filename,frmdata){
       var request = $http({method:'get', url:APP_URL+'/exports/'+id+'/download/'+filename, data:frmdata,responseType:'arraybuffer'});
       return request;        
    }
```