# Error while zipping a folder using Easyzip

Tags: node.js

Using Easyzip I am trying to zip a folder along with its files. The below mentioned code is not working properly. I get an error 'error occurred while extracting files'. Is there any other method to zip a folder with all its files and subfolders?

Here is my back-end code :-

```
var zip2 = new EasyZip();
zip2.zipFolder('./downloads/'+application._id,function(){
  zip2.writeToFile('./downloads/'+application._id+'.zip');

  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename='+application._id+'.zip');
  res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/zip');

  var fs = require('fs');
  var filestream = fs.createReadStream('./downloads/'+application._id+'.zip');

filestream.pipe(res);
});
});
```

My angular.js code

```
  $http.post('/download/archive/' + stateParams._id, {year: year}).success(function (data) {
           var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/zip'});
           console.log(file)
           saveAs(file, 'application.zip');

       });
```

Please help me to solve these. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even I had the same problem and was able to solve it. For more details check: [Zip generated by EasyZip is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433045/zip-generated-by-easyzip-is-not-working-properly/32453611#32453611) Hope that this may help you.