# How can I download zip file using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, download, zip

I am using angularjs.I am getting zip file URL from the server.

I am using below code to download my file.

`<a href="{{filename}}" download="{{filename}}">Example 1</a>`

Filename comes from the angular controller.

From the above code I will be able to download the file but in the download folder.How can I download that file in specified location ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to download a zip file using angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158115/how-to-download-a-zip-file-using-angular)

Answer (score 0):

just open that link in new tab it will automatically be download.

**window.open(wholeURLToDownload);**

Comment: Thanks JaiminRaval it is working but I want to download and save that file in the pre defined location.How can I do that ?

Comment: can you download a file from chrome in specified folder? The same is the answer for your question.

Comment: you can set the default download location first and then try to download, it will be downloaded into that specified folder