# Swagger UI blank PDF download

Tags: java, pdf, swagger, jhipster, swagger-ui

I'm having a problem with Swagger UI when trying to download a PDF file. Everything works fine outside Swagger UI (using `curl` or Postman there is no problem), but when I try to download via Swagger UI I get a blank PDF.

I'm using Springfox 2.50 (microservice JHipster application), and the response from my Java Spring method is a `HttpEntity<byte[]>`.

Edit:
I found similar problem: [Swagger UI Download PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591731/swagger-ui-download-pdf) but it does not have any answers.

Comment: @SurenSrapyan: Please don't use backticks `\`code\`` to format proper nouns, file extensions, etc. It's reserved for actual code - variable names, class names, etc.

Comment: I didn't do it. My post was edited by another user.

Comment: Yes, my comment was addressed to the user who edited your post.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have one of the following issues with your setup:

1) The `@produces` on your server (and therefore in the swagger definition) may not be correct.  Please make sure you have `produces: application/pdf` in your operation.

2) Your operation that returns the pdf may have no schema associated with it.  For swagger-ui to render a proper download, you need to have a schema.  The correct schema would be:

```
schema:
  type: string
  format: byte
```

3) Your server must be returning the correct `Content-Type`.  Please make sure it's `application/pdf` in the headers

You might want to try the [petstore sample](http://petstore.swagger.io) against your server as that is the latest build of swagger-ui, the one bundled with SpringFox may be a bit behind.

Comment: 1) I define in @RequestMapping the produces value. Still not working
2) How do I define the schema values with spring o swagger annotations?
3) Content-Type header is correct: "application/pdf"

Thanks for your help