# Does angular provide any library or plugin to convert server side binary data to pdf or excel format

Tags: angularjs, date

I have a requirement that my server will be sending data in binary form but I have to show the data in pdf or excel format. 
Does angular provide any way to do so.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21732039/1618775 
Try this, it can be your solution. 
I advice you convert binary to pdf at serverside.