# How to open a PDF In angular from URL

Tags: angularjs, pdf

So currently I have a list of PDF files that are displayed on a page with a link to their location. How would I go about downloading or viewing the file without using external libraries?

Currently the URL to the PDF's location just opens a new tab which is a blank web page without showing the PDF.

I'll post my code below. any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<div class="body">
                    <div class="scroll-container">
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr dir-paginate="action in test | itemsPerPage: 14">
                                <td class="date"><a href="{{ action.Url }}" target="_blank">{{ action.Name }}</a></td>
                                <!--<td class="date"></td>-->
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                    <div class="total-container">
                        <div class="top">
                            <div class="pagination">
                                <dir-pagination-controls></dir-pagination-controls>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>**strong text**
```

Comment: http://www.unknownerror.org/opensource/angular-app/angular-app/q/stackoverflow/21628378/angularjs-display-blob-pdf-in-an-angular-app

Comment: @NimeshGami thats just a copy of the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628378/angularjs-display-blob-pdf-in-an-angular-app

Comment: I've already tried this but doesn't work on multiple browsers

Comment: You can use `angular-pdf` here is link https://github.com/sayanee/angularjs-pdf

Answer (score 0):

Right now, the pdf is opening in a new tab because of target `target="_blank"`. This is the default browser behavior. If you want to open the pdf in the same tab, then you can use an iFrame.

```
<iframe ng-src="{{action.Url}}" width="800px" height="600px"></iframe>
```

Comment: Opening in a new tab is what i want to happen, I just can't seem to view the PDF, sorry if that wasn't implied.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it myself but thanks!

```
<td class="date"><a href="MyIPAddressHere{{ action.Url }}" target="_blank">{{ action.Name }}</a></td>
```