# AngularJS/Ionic displaying image from API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, encoding, arrays

I'm attempting to load a PNG image into my Ionic app via a web API from a third-party source, but it's failing to display. The response I receive contains data for the PNG which I believe to be a byte array data and begins like this:

> �PNG   IHDR��R�l  pHY....

This starts by making the following API call:

```
function getImage(authToken) {
  var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": imgLocation,
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "auth-token": authToken,
      "cache-control": "no-cache"
    }
  }
  return $http(settings)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response;
    })
    .catch(function(e) {
      return e.data;
    }); 
}
```

The data is then applied to the 'image' variable inside of my controller

```
$scope.image = response.data;
```

I then convert the data into a base64 string, using the the Base64 encode/decode I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript

And then finally, into my HTML I have this:

```
<img ng-src="data:image/PNG;base64,{{image}}">
```

The result is an empty box in place where an image would be shown, and not a broken image link. I've attempted various solutions found on Stackoverflow but I can't seem to get anything to stick. It should also be noted that I do have the following in my config:

```
$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|file|ftp|blob):|data:image\//);
```

... and in my index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; img-src 'self' data: *">
```

So again, I'm attempting to load PNG images via API calls into my app. I believe I'm receiving a byte array representation of the image, but when I attempt to convert it to base64, the image doesn't load. Additionally, I'm not receiving any errors in the console.

If anyone could offer me some insight, it would be of great help, thanks.

Comment: I've also attempted to turn the data into a "Blob" object and then read it from window.FileReader() only to get the exact same output as expected. However the image still doesn't show up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

there is a thread with your answer. You have to create a fileurl from your object and make angular trust it. As for the pdf you should be able to add the image to your html with {{fileURL}} using the img tag like in the example.

[AngularJS: Display blob (.pdf) in an angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628378/angularjs-display-blob-pdf-in-an-angular-app)