# Display pdf using angularjs

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, pdf, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to download a pdf file from server and show it in browser. The web api method that I have returns the file as httpResponseMessage and that is working fine because it returns the file. But on the AngularJs side I am not able to display the file. Can somebody help me understand what am I missing?

**Web Api Method:**

```
  public HttpResponseMessage GetHelpReferenceDocs(Guid streamKey)
    {
        var fakeFileName = GetStream(streamKey); // If this succeeds, stream is known and unexpired.

        // Internal file name
        string staticFileName = helpFiles[fakeFileName];

        var mappedPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Static/" + staticFileName);

        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var stream = new FileStream(mappedPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = Path.GetFileName(mappedPath);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
        return result;


    }
```

**AngularJS:**

```
  function loadDocument(fileName) {

        REST.post(commonService.constants.webapi.helpFileStreamKey + fileName)
      .then(function(response) {
          var streamGuid = response.data;

          REST.get(commonService.constants.webapi.helpReferenceGuide + streamGuid).then(function (response) {

             $window.open(response.data);

          });

            })
        .catch(function (e) { $scope.errorHandler(moduleName, e); })
        .finally($scope.waitOn);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution. Needed to modify my Angular code a little bit and it worked fine. Here is the code if somebody facing the same problem:

```
 function loadDocument(fileName) {

        REST.post(commonService.constants.webapi.helpFileStreamKey + 'firmUserGuid')
      .then(function(response) {
          var streamGuid = response.data;

          REST.get(commonService.constants.webapi.helpReferenceGuide + streamGuid).then(function (response) {
              var pdfFileURL = response.config.url;
              $window.open(pdfFileURL);

          });

            })
        .catch(function (e) { $scope.errorHandler(moduleName, e); })
        .finally($scope.waitOn);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628378/angularjs-display-blob-pdf-in-an-angular-app), or alternatively you can try an npm module specifically for displaying pdfs where this is already taken care of for you, [such as this one.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-pdf)