# how to show pdf in iframe from blob in angular6?

Tags: angular, blob

I need some help, I dont have any idea how to convert blob to pdf and show it in iframe
I got this response from BackEnd (not copy all)

```
PK
```

! Gæ2[Content_Types].xml´Ko!÷úFl+§ªª<Î¢©6RS©[wlá!¸Nâß;O5éÈLk³i¸s>`X_?ºxµ³%»Z®XV:¥í®d?o¿,Þ³"¢°JÔÎBÉÙõæõ«õíÑC,HmcÉöþçQîÁ¸t,U*@z
;î¼;àoW«w\:`qÛ¬?A%5¨¹#!9+>vý¨   ïk-R7U>©»ó°{!Ô¦   nÓo§%Mû´"@Oà=Xõbýø¤lûÄ½öñM?ï´A+(nDÀoÂtAqåäÁPÄòôtLä¹ªÒF}ãæ#­¬©cÅmOqÈCDg~ksWgã¦Ô{0[DùÉ­5ÄËt¾éx@$AÞ9ðÛÙ(þ0OTÎ¡uc5Fë$XapN"HgólvT ò¡    I¤=áüê/ÎxÖ×%¿3Oyb[CÞ:  áÁùo2é6ÝóühmNERÏöt¤¿!üÇB£^øYÇâHÖgú?ë_³»£üB7áÏ6¯*ãÖGæoo¼ßÿÿPK
!¿@ar_rels/.rels¬ÛJÄ0ïß!ä~îz@dÓ½aïDêÉ´6©î¾½qµ°Ô{>¾Éz³³={Ãw/3tÊkãZÉêûÅ
gÀiè½CÉ÷ø¦:?[?bRgBbâäQ¸"©-¤Ât¹Óøhò1¶"zÅª,¯EüÍàÕÉ¶Zò¸ÕÕûÿcò!æéH&ßÕ[$ÉµW¹"¹8.tyºo£ðÎ«Á¢£c^¸#tõ´0et5§yûÇ)¥åJãÄÏ»Zè¯òÍjÞ7DÝ`þÈj¾{ÅKÀöSH~JõÿÿPK
!

all i have tried is use

```
this._endpointService.getData('/myGet')
           .then((res:any) => {
            let blob = new Blob([res.error.text], { type: 'application/pdf' })
            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            this.tryDoctype = blob
})
```

then i dont know what's next i must do.

Comment: Check this:https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer

Comment: Your variable `fileURL` should contain the URL of the PDF file. You will need this to display the PDF.

Comment: sorry, ng2-pdf-viewer didnt help me at all.. :(

i get pdf file as the blob type like at the top top. am i doing right at my question? or i am totaly wrong how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display blob (.pdf) in an angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628378/display-blob-pdf-in-an-angular-app)

Answer (score 2):

Please try below:

```
//import this ref
this._endpointService.getData('/myGet')
           .then((res:any) => {
    //change in response
    let blob = new Blob([res.error.text.blob()], { type: 'application/pdf' })
    let fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    //if you have any error then try this
    //this.tryDoctype = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(fileURL);

    this.tryDoctype = fileURL;
})
```

Assign fileURL to Iframe

```
  <iframe *ngIf="tryDoctype" [src]="tryDoctype" width="950" height="600"></iframe>
```