# How can I use Ajax to access a file once the user selects it?

Tags: html, ajax

I use a standard `<input type="file">` tag for the user to select a file, how can I use Ajax to access that file and read its contents once the user selects it?

Comment: Clarify "access". Do you want to open and read the file contents? You need to upload it, you can upload it with a javascript script *MAYBE*

Comment: yes read its content

Comment: Please update your question with examples of what you've tried already and why these things did not work. Also clarify exactly what result you are looking for. Read **[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Comment: Are you talking about accessing the file before it is uploaded by the user submitting the input form, or are you asking about accessing the file once the user has given it to the server to store via the file upload HTML input mechanism?

Comment: once the user has given it to the server, is it possible before?

Comment: [Does reading other questions on this topic help you?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658590/in-javascript-how-do-you-open-a-file-from-the-server)

Comment: yeah thanks, I think that will do

Answer (score 1):

Use Change event as defined below and access the file using FileReader Object. An example can be seen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript)

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="changeFile(this)" />
```