# Using $window or $location to Redirect in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, angular-ui-router

The app I am working on contains various states (using ui-router), where some states require you to be logged in, others are publicly available.

I have created a method that validly checks whether a user is logged in, what I am currently having issues with is actually redirecting to our login-page when necessary. It should be noted that the login page is not currently placed within the AngularJS app.

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $location, $window) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

        if (toState.data.loginReq && !$rootScope.me.loggedIn) {
            var landingUrl = $window.location.host + "/login";
            console.log(landingUrl);
            $window.open(landingUrl, "_self");
        }
    });
});
```

The console.log shows the intended URL properly. The line after that, I have tried practically everything from $window.open to window.location.href and no matter what I've tried no redirect happens.

Comment: Should probably add that there is server side authentication on the data as well, so the above is not the only authentication, it is more a matter of convenience to redirect to the login-page, instead of showing a mostly empty page.

Comment: you need the native `location` object using `$window.location=...`

Comment: INstead you could consider to make it all a AngularJS including your authentication -- see this post http://frederiknakstad.com/2013/01/21/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular-js/

Comment: The plan is to include everything (including login) inside the AngularJS app eventually, but as we are currently making the transition to AngularJS, the registration/login screen seems to be the least important at this stage.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I believe the way to do this is `$location.url('/RouteTo/Login');`

Say my route for my login view was `/Login`, I would say `$location.url('/Login')` to navigate to that route.

For locations outside of the Angular app (i.e. no route defined), plain old JavaScript will serve:

```
window.location = "http://www.my-domain.example/login"
```

Comment: Just tried that. Unfortunately, that redirects to www.domain.com/app/RouteTo/login rather than www.domain.com/login

Comment: Right, that wasn't mean to be literal. I don't know what you've defined as the route for your login view. Place whatever that route might be in the the argument for the $location.url() method. I've edited the answer for clarity.

Comment: Ah right. The issue here is that $location.url still redirects to a sub-path of the app. So using $location.url('/login') redirects to www.domain.com/app/login rather than www.domain.com/login

Comment: What have you defined as your route for your login view?

Comment: Well, as stated in the question, currently the login page sits outside the AngularJS app. Hence the need to redirect to www.domain.com/login rather than a path within the app.

Comment: I apologize; I missed that detail. I've edited my answer accordingly. I tested to ensure it works in an Angular app of my own to be sure.

Comment: Ah just saw your edit now. This would indeed solve it. My issue seemed to be the lack of http:// before the hostname

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location  says:
It does not cause a full page reload when the browser URL is changed. To reload the page after changing the URL, use the lower-level API, $window.location.href.
So... if you need to ensure reloaded page...use $window.location.href.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning you should probably use `$window` instead of `window` (source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906180/difference-between-window-and-window-in-ionicframework)

Answer (score 42):

It seems that for full page reload `$window.location.href` is the preferred way.

> It does not cause a full page reload when the browser URL is changed. To reload the page after changing the URL, use the lower-level API, $window.location.href.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Answer (score 20):

It might help you! [demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/bhMcEO/)

AngularJs Code-sample

```
var app = angular.module('urlApp', []);
app.controller('urlCtrl', function ($scope, $log, $window) {
    $scope.ClickMeToRedirect = function () {
        var url = "http://" + $window.location.host + "/Account/Login";
        $log.log(url);
        $window.location.href = url;
    };
});
```

HTML Code-sample

```
<div ng-app="urlApp">
    <div ng-controller="urlCtrl">
        Redirect to <a href="#" ng-click="ClickMeToRedirect()">Click Me!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure from what version, but I use 1.3.14 and you can just use:

```
window.location.href = '/employee/1';
```

No need to inject `$location` or `$window` in the controller and no need to get the current host address.

Answer (score -11):

You have to put:

<**html** ng-app="urlApp" ng-controller="urlCtrl">

This way the angular function can access into "window" object

Comment: Don't be afraid!