# Difference between $window and window in Ionicframework

Tags: ionic-framework

What is the exact difference between $window and window in ionic-framework?

For example, in the localstorage tutorial at learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/localstorage/ both $window and window are used.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`$window`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) is an Angular service wrapping the global variable `window`, mainly to make it possible to mock it for unit tests:

> A reference to the browser's window object. While window is globally available in JavaScript, it causes testability problems, because it is a global variable. In angular we always refer to it through the $window service, so it may be overridden, removed or mocked for testing.

If you look [at the source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/window.js#L45), you'll see that there is not much more behind it:

```js
function $WindowProvider() {
  this.$get = valueFn(window);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both are not related to ionic-framework as such.

window is a browser object which represents the window containing the DOM. 
'document' that we use for javascript is a property of window object
window.document.

refer this 
[browser window object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window)

where $window is a service created in angular which can be injected to any service or controller written in angular again to make use of its APIs.

refer to this for $window

[$window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window)