# $window.location.href NOT WORKING in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, authentication, window.location

I'm building a basic **AngularJS** Login page and the **$window.location.href** did not re-direct the page to a new html in my system, hosted by WAMP. I even tried re-directing it to google. Nothing happens. I tried all the available solutions here and nothing seems to work. Any solutions ? 

JS followed by HTML

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';


  $scope.submit = function() {
    if ($scope.username && $scope.password) {
      var user = $scope.username;
      var pass = $scope.password;
      if (pass == "admin" && user == "admin@admin.com") {
        alert("Login Successful");
        $window.location.href = "http://google.com"; //Re-direction to some page
      } else if (user != "admin@admin.com") {
        alert("Invalid username");
      } else if (pass != "admin" && user == "admin@admin.com") {
        alert("Invalid password");
      }
    } else {
      alert("Invalid Login");
    }
  }


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="login.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <form>
    <label>Username:</label>
    <input type="email" ng-model="username" class="lab1" />
    </br>
    </br>
    <label></label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" ng-model="password" class="lab2">
    </br>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="submit()" class="buttonclass">login</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try withouth the `$` sign. **window.location.href = "admin@admin.com"**

Comment: Use basic Javascript window redirect .. that is without $. window.location.href.

Comment: It worked. Thank you :) But why doesn't it work with the dollar sign ?

Comment: @VarunKN check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794115/using-window-or-location-to-redirect-in-angularjs-resolved).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In angular js you can use `$location`. Inject it in your controller :

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $location) { ... }
```

And if you want to redirect to google use its `url()` method :

```
$location.url('http://google.fr');
```

you can also use `path()` method for relative url :

```
$location.path('home'); // will redirect you to 'yourDomain.xx/home'
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: False. You don't "have to use"; You **can** use. It's not mandatory to use $location just because it's a service. Depending on the situation, you use  window.location without a problem.

Comment: See Jim Grimmett's answer. It seems to be more accurate.

Answer (score 3):

It is worth noting the [current documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) for `$location`. Specifically the quote:

> **When should I use $location?**
>
> Any time your application needs to react to a change in the current URL or if you want to change the current URL in the browser.
>
> **What does it not do?**
>
> It does not cause a full page reload when the browser URL is changed. To reload the page after changing the URL, use the lower-level API, $window.location.href.

If you need to redirect the browser to a new page, $window.location is definitely recommended.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this,

var homeApp = angular.module('HomeApp', []);

homeApp.controller('HomeController', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
    $scope.loginname = "Login To Demo App";
    $scope.login = function () {

        var name = $scope.username;
        var pwd = $scope.password;
        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '../Account/LoginAccount',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': undefined
            },
            params: { username: name, password: pwd }
        }

        $http(req).then(function (responce) {

            var url = '';
            if (responce.data == "True") {
                url = '../Account/WelcomePage';
                $window.location.href = url;
            }
            else {
                url = '../Account/Login';
                $window.location.href = url;
            }
        }, function (responce) {

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe your code is not working, because you are not declaring $window in the controller parameters

Answer (score 0):

Angular has its own location handler named `$location` which I prefer to use in angular app;

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
```

inject to your controller and use as following;

```
$location.path('http://foo.bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `$window.location.href` in AngularJS

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope,$window) {
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.submitForm = function (formData){
    $window.location.href = "jobs";
    };
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents -

I could not get `$window.location.href` or `$location.path` to work to navigate away from a page. In the documentation for `$location` (under **caveats**) it says:

> The $location service allows you to change only the URL; it does not allow you to reload the page. When you need to change the URL and reload the page or navigate to a different page, please use a lower level API, $window.location.href.

[$location Caveats](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#caveats)

Documentation for $window is... lacking. Regardless, neither of the services worked for me in the controller (though $location.path works in my `index.run` file).

In this project I am using ui-router, so doing this worked:
`$state.go('state.name');` -- where state.name is the string of the state/page name to which the user wants to go, i.e. `'index.users'`