# Error: $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop on $locationChangeStart in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a session redirect if the user is not logged in. The code is working as I expected. However, when I take a look on the console, An error occurs (as in indicated in the title). I can not seem to fix this and I need some help.

```
var domainName = window.location.href;
var domainName = domainName.split("/");
var domainName = domainName[0] + "//" + domainName[2];

var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.run(run);

run.$inject = ["$window", "$rootScope", "$cookies"];

function run($window, $rootScope, $cookies){

    // Runs everytime the URL changes
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, current, previous) {
        // If the user is not logged-in and is not trying to access the register or log-in, It will go back to the log-in page
        // if(!$cookies.get('user') && current != domainName+"/#/"){
        if(current != domainName+"/#/"){
            $window.location.href = domainName+"/#/";
        //  Create a scope that will remind the users regarding the session
        //  $rootScope.sessionError = "Please Enter Exam Code before taking the exam";
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message describes, you are facing an infinite loop. 
When the event `$locationChangeStart` is fired you check the url and redirect to another page. When you redirect the url is changed again, firing the `$locationChangeStart` again and so on. 
You need to find another way to validate if the user is logged or not.

I don't know if it's going to work, but try checking if `current` is different from `previous`.

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, current, previous) {
    if(current !== previous && current != domainName+"/#/"){
        $window.location.href = domainName+"/#/";
    }
});
```

I suggest you to use $location for changing the URL. 
[Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) 
[Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794115/using-window-or-location-to-redirect-in-angularjs)

Comment: the condition does not trigger anymore, may I know why you suggested $location over $window?

Comment: I think it's the angular way of doing such thing and `$location` provides some useful methods. The `$window` is just a reference to window object, but off course, you can keep using `$window` wihtout any problem.  I think it's more like a convention.

Comment: You're welcome ;)      About your question, I can't think in a solution to resolve the loop problem without removing the redirect from the event. Because every time the url changes will trigger the event again and again. I think you need rethink the way you're doing this or create a validation to not enter in a infinite loop.

Comment: Yes, probably will try a different approach! (y)

Comment: I finally solved it! I used $location insted of $window and it worked like a charm!