# How to change search parameter with $location

Tags: angularjs, location

I want to use $location to change url search parameter. For example:

I have a url, example.com/path?id=12345&target=_self

how could I use $location to change the url to

example.com/path?id=54321&target=_blank

When I use $location.search({id: '54321', target='_blank'}), it just append a

new parameter to the end of url instead of change the url.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) documentation says that you have to write this like below:

```
$location.search('id', '54321')
         .search('target', '_blank');
```

Comment: Thanks, use this method is the same, just append a new search after the previous url instead of changing current url search.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should refer to [this Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794115/using-window-or-location-to-redirect-in-angularjs) post.

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, use this method is the same, just append a new search after the previous url instead of changing current url search.