# How to handle downloads of an image from a nodejs server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, express, download

I am currently learning node.js, and recently came across a situation where I'd like to download an image stored on the server upon clicking a button on the webpage. I have created an endpoint, to which the controller passes two arguments:
- Name of the image to be downloaded (the directory is fixed)
- Name by which to download the image

I have tried the solutions given in [Download a file from NodeJS Server using Express](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7288814/4396392)

I'm using angular to populate the buttons and trigger the download, as follows:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Image tags">
    <button ng-repeat="tag in imageTags" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning" ng-click="download(tag)">{{tag}}</button>
</div>
```

And here is my controller:

```
$scope.download = function(tagName) {
    tagName = tagName.replace(/\W+/g, '-');
    Clarifai.download(tagName, UploadSuccess.uploadedFile)
        // UploadSuccess.uploadedFile contains the name of the file to be downloaded.
        .success(function(data) {
            //do something
        });
}
```

which calls the following factory method:

```
download: function(tagName, imageName) {
    return $http.get('/api/clarifai/tagDownload/' + tagName + "/" + imageName);
}
```

And here's the relevant part of my routes file:

```
app.get('/api/clarifai/tagDownload/:tagName/:imageName', function(req, res) {
    // Ignore tagName for now.
    console.log("Begin download");
    var img = path.resolve('image_dump/OutputDump/' + req.params.imageName);
    // Returns the expected path for the file
    var filename = path.basename(img);
    var mimetype = mime.lookup(img);

    console.log(filename);
    console.log(mimetype);

    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
    res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);

    var filestream = fs.createReadStream(img);
    filestream.pipe(res);
    res.on('finish', function(){
        console.log("Download complete");
    });
});
```

So all the flow works till this point, and upon clicking one of the buttons, I get the output as follows:

```
Begin download
Jon-1477683540996.jpg
image/jpeg
GET /api/clarifai/tagDownload/people/Jon-1477683540996.jpg 200 5.296 ms -
Download complete
```

But I see no sign of the downloaded file anywhere. No dialogs on any browser. All answers I've read so far seem to mention that the download is handled by the `pipe` call. But with no success for me.

I have also tried `res.download(img)`, but with the same results.

My approach has been to handle this using the callback inside the controller. But I'm unable to figure out how to do so. What am I missing / doing wrong? Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you're using Express, you should be able to just do `res.download('image_dump/OutputDump/' + req.params.imageName)`

Comment: @adeneo, I have tried that. But with no luck. No download dialogs. File is not present in my default downloads directory either.

Comment: If you just type the URL in the browser, does it start a download then? Buttons don't generally redirect, neither does Angular ?

Comment: Ouch. That did the trick! 
Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here's how I solved the problem:
In my controller, instead of using:

```js
$http.get('/api/clarifai/tagDownload/' + tagName + "/" + imageName);
```

I had to do:

```js
path = "/api/clarifai/tagDownload/" + tagName + "/" + imageName;
$window.location.href = path;
```

As adeneo had pointed out, the reason to this was that clicking on a button in Angular doesn't redirect. So, this had to be manually triggered using Angular's `$window.location.href` API.

Some alternate ways to do this can also be found in this answer: [Using $window or $location to Redirect in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794115/using-window-or-location-to-redirect-in-angularjs)