# Using angularJs mvc How to Redirect from one page to another page when we select value from autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Here i did upto binding values into autocomplete text but when i select the value why its not transfor that page please Guid me

```
  public class CoursesList
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CourseId { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
        public string Countrolle { get; set; }
        public string Action { get; set; }
    }
```

Here i'm Using Joining concept for Joining two tables

```
 public IEnumerable<CoursesList> GetCourses()
        {
            var x = from n in db.Courses
                    join c_List in db.CourseDetails on n.CourseId equals c_List.CourseId
                    select new CoursesList
                    {
                        CourseId=n.CourseId,
                        CourseName=n.CourseName,
                        Countrolle=c_List.Countrolle,Action=c_List.Action
                    };
            return x.ToList();
        }
```

**Auto.Cshtml**

```
<div ng-controller="Helloctrls">

        <div ng-cloak="" angucomplete-alt id="ex1_dropdown" placeholder="Search countries" pause="100" selected-object="afterSelectedCountry" class="postit"
             local-data="Countries" search-fields="CourseName" title-field="CourseName" minlength="1" maximumlength="3" input-class="form-control form-control-small"
             match-class="highlight">

        </div>

        <div ng-repeat="BindService in SelectedCountry">
            @{
                var uri = Url.Action("{{BindService.Countrolle}}");

                uri = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uri);

            }
            <a href="@uri"></a>

        </div>
       </div>
```

**Angular.js**

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['angucomplete-alt'])
        .controller('Helloctrls', ['$scope','$http',function ($scope,$http) {

            $scope.Countries = [];
            $scope.SelectedCountry = null;

            $scope.afterSelectedCountry = function (selected) {
                if (selected) {
                    $scope.SelectedCountry = selected.originalObject;
                }
            }

            //Populate data from database 
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/Dynamic/Courses'
            }).then(function (data) {
                $scope.Countries = data.data;
            }, function () {
                alert('Error');
            })

        }])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using $location service in angularJs, here is a sample code based on your code

```
$scope.afterSelectedCountry = function (selected) {
            if (selected) {
                $scope.SelectedCountry = selected.originalObject;
                $location.url('/someview');
            }
        }
```

or

if you want to redirect outside of the app, you can use standard javascript

```
$scope.afterSelectedCountry = function (selected) {
            if (selected) {
                $scope.SelectedCountry = selected.originalObject;
                window.location.href = someurl;
            }
        }
```

For more details, please take a look at [Using $window or $location to Redirect in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794115/using-window-or-location-to-redirect-in-angularjs)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by multiple urls? Update your question with more details with examples of multiple urls.

Comment: will u come in teamviewr